# Question with floating point addition

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision

```
float totalAmount = 0;
.
.
.//totalAmount assigned value 1.05 correctly
.
totalAmount  += float.Parse(dataRow["Amt"].ToString()); //where dataRow["Amt"] has value 4.93
```

The answer I get for totalAmount is 5.97999954 instead of 5.98

Why is this happening?

Comment: Yeah, why the heck *doesn't* `4.93 + 1.05` equal `4.98` ?? ;)

Comment: I assume you mean instead of **5**.98

Comment: You could get away with doing this if the internal object is a float.
(float)dataRow["Amt"]

Comment: sorry for the typos. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Use "decimal" instead of "float" if you want exact representations of decimal quantities.  "float" gives exact representations of binary quantities.

Comment: This question is so common it should be added to the FAQ. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/ for a good overview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You state that `totalAmount` is 1.05, before the accumulation. That would give expected results of:

```
1.05
4.93 +
------
5.98
```

You are getting 5.97999954, which is basically the answer as best represented by IEEE floating point, which is a binary format that cannot exactly express every decimal number. For instance, the rather common 0.1<sub>10</sub> has an infinite binary floating point representation `.0001100110011...`<sub>2</sub>.

And a Wikipedia link, for good measure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems ;)

Comment: Hey, I even learned something. Neither .1 nor .01 are representable in floating point. Which makes squaring .1 an interesting case.

Comment: I didn't even know we were having a war. I was just editing as requested.

Comment: Opimistic concurrency at it's worst :) Luckily there's a rollback feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to representing [base-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) numbers in a [base-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base-2) system.

Floating point math on computers always does this. If you know the level of precision you'll need you should use the appropriate decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

jdmichal is correct, but I'll add that, if you actually want this to add up correctly, you could use the Decimal type (including decimal literals).

Comment: There are many options available to fix this, depending on the context of the problem. For instance, fixed precision (such as currency) allows separation of the decimal portion into an integral type.