# Java loss of precision

Tags: java, string, precision

I have a problem concerned with losing of precision

my task is to print numbers as strings

```
int exponent = ...
int[] Mantissas = { 1, 2, 5 };
double dataStep = java.lang.Math.pow(10.0, exponent) * Mantissas[mantissaIndex];
...
for (int i = 0; i < NSteps; i++)
                    steps[i] = firstStep + i * dataStep;
draw(steps);
```

for example, 0.2*7=1.4000000000000001; 0.0000014/10=1.3999999999999998E-7

how to figure out this problem?

**UPD**: The main problem is **string** output formating. i don't bother about losting of about 0.00000001 value.
Now I solved it as String.format("%f", value),
but I think it's not good approach

Comment: The most frequently asked question on all of stackoverflow.

Comment: We should have a fubar badge for asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others you have to use **java.math.BigDecimal** instead of float/double. This however comes with its own set of problems.

For instance when you call BigDecimal(double) the value you pass in will be expanded to its full representation:

```
BigDecimal oneTenth = new BigDecimal(0.1);
BigDecimal oneMillion = new BigDecimal(1000000);
oneTenth.multiply(oneMillion)
out> 100000.0000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625000000
```

But when you use the BigDecimal(String) constructor the eact value is represented and you get

```
BigDecimal oneTenth = new BigDecimal("0.1");
BigDecimalr oneMillion = new BigDecimal(1000000);
oneTenth.multiply(oneMillion)
out> 100000.0
```

You can read more on BigDecimal's limitations in Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter's splendid [Java puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com) book and in [this](http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/04/26/the-evil-bigdecimal-constructor/) informative article. Finally note that toString on BigDecimal's will print in scientific notation so you will properly have to use **toPlainString** instead.

Answer (score 2):

The double type does not have infinite precision and cannot represent decimals exactly. You are observing normal rounding errors. For arbitrary precision arithmetic, you will need to use java.math.BigDecimal instead.

Comment: ok,
java.math.BigDecimal m=new BigDecimal(1.4).setScale(1000);
                    m=m.divide(new BigDecimal(10).setScale(1000));  
System.out.println(m);
the output is 0.1399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
;I want to print "0.14" on my chart control

Comment: Don't use new BigDecimal(double) use either new BigDecimal(String) or BigDecimal.valueOf(double). new BigDecimal(double) will act exactly like a double.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "floating point numbers" on SO and you'll get a slew of answers as to why this happens.  It has to do with how floating point numbers are represented in computers.

[How is floating point stored? When does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter)

Another article on the matter - [Floating Point Approximation](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/12/floating_point_approximation/)