# Java slopes are not equal when they should be

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a program that finds 2 slopes and them compares them to see if they are equal. I am using doubles for this. I am finding that even though my slopes should be "equal" they are coming out a little bit off and so aren't showing as being equal. For example I get one slope of 1.0000000000000009 and 0.9999999999999999. So they should be equal in theory, but they aren't.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Step #1: Show us the code.

Comment: I think this is probably a precision issue.  Often times when you operate on floats and doubles a little precision is lost.  I think this will help you solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389457/java-loss-of-precision

Comment: This is a floating-point FAQ.  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996

Comment: Lots of duplicates when googling *Java double comparison*: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11390853/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/434657/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1726254/1065197 ...

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: @AlanKrueger - good link

Comment: @user1428716 I've just seen it posted on other instances of this question on StackOverflow. If I didn't post it, someone else would have shortly.  =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using doubles, you will never fix this: there's limitations in the way decimal numbers are represented, which accumulate across your calculations, and give you these tiny differences. A good code audit would actually warn you of equalities between doubles.

The one way to handle it is to ensure that the absolute value of the difference is under a certain limit you set.

[Here's an article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0114/#N10255) on floating point number representation and the hazards of comparisons.

Alternatively, you could switch to better classes for precise number handling, such as `BigDecimal`.

Comment: BigDecimal better than double in two cases: if decimal fractions are special, or if there is a suitable finite precision greater than that provided by double. Calculating a slope might involve fractions such as 1/3, that are not exactly representable in BigDecimal regardless of scale, leading to rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

to compare the 2 slopes you could set some PRECISION_LEVEL and then compare as follows

```
final double PRECISON_LEVEL = 0.01;
if(Math.abs(slope1 - slope2) < PRECISION_LEVEL) {
    System.out.println("Equal");
} 
else {
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```