# C++ , experience problems to convert double to int

Tags: c++

Need the code bellow to accept values in double and convert in int

```cpp
using namespace std;

SymbolTable symbolTable;

void parseAssignments();

int main()

{

    Expression* expression;

    char paren, comma;

    cout << "Enter expression: ";

    cin >> paren;

    expression = SubExpression::parse();

    cin >> comma;

    parseAssignments();

    cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << endl; 

    return 0;

}

void parseAssignments()

{

    char assignop, delimiter;

    string variable;
    double value;

    do

    {

        variable = parseName();

        cin >> ws >> assignop >> value >> delimiter;

        symbolTable.insert(variable, value);

    }

    while (delimiter == ',');

}
```

Comment: Why you are accepting double and string to int type?
Provided code not give complete picture.

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: It seems that the problem is just with the conversion of `value` from `double` to `int`. Strip away the extraneous code and focus on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to convert from double to int is to set an int equal to a double. The int will store the truncated value, meaning it does not round after the decimal, merely ignores it. For example:

```cpp
double pi = 3.14;
int piApprox = pi;

cout<<pi<<endl; // This will output 3.14
cout<<piApprox<<endl; //This will output 3
```

Hope this helps, your questions is very similar to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127962/c-float-to-int). That one goes into more detail about the engineering aspects of how floating point numbers work in computers and precautions in converting from float to int.