# Can someone explain this: 0.2 + 0.1 = 0.30000000000000004?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

> **Duplicates:**
> [How is floating point stored? When does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter)
>
> [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Why does the following occur in the Python Interpreter?

```
>>> 0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3
5.551115123125783e-17
>>> 0.1+0.1
0.2
>>> 0.2+0.1
0.30000000000000004
>>> 0.3-0.3
0.0
>>> 0.2+0.1
0.30000000000000004
>>>
```

Why doesn't `0.2 + 0.1 = 0.3`?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's because `.1` cannot be represented exactly in a binary floating point representation. If you try

```
>>> .1
```

Python will respond with `.1` because it only prints up to a certain precision, but there's already a small round-off error. The same happens with `.3`, but when you issue

```
>>> .2 + .1
0.30000000000000004
```

then the round-off errors in `.2` and `.1` accumulate. Also note:

```
>>> .2 + .1 == .3
False
```

Comment: @MarkByers: good point, expanded my answer.

Comment: and 0.2 ;-) neither of the 3 can be represented as (-1)^sign * 1.fraction * 2^(exp-127) see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 referenced from accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter/57031#57031 from the duplicate source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter

Comment: so computers can't add `.1` and `.3`? That seems pretty useless then

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Answer (score 17):

Not all floating point numbers are exactly representable on a finite machine. Neither 0.1 nor 0.2 are exactly representable in binary floating point. And nor is 0.3.

A number is exactly representable if it is of the form a/b where a and b are an integers and b  is a power of 2. Obviously, the data type needs to have a large enough significand to store the number also.

I recommend [Rob Kennedy's useful webpage](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float) as a nice tool to explore representability.