# Trying to add up an array, but result returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html, addition, nan

So I have a string called hoursString that looks like

```
4.3|2.4|3.4|3.0|2.64|3.0|1.0|0.0|2.6|3.4|
```

I split the string into an array and what I am trying to do is add up all the numbers and return it to the html page in the div "test".

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var hours=hoursString.split("|");

    var total=0;
    for (var i=0;i<hours.length;i++)
        {
        total += hours[i];
        }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=total;
```

The result is NaN.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
4.3|2.4|3.4|3.0|2.64|3.0|1.0|0.0|2.6|3.4|
```

remove the last |, split will otherwise add an empty string at the end of the array which will give NaN and NaN + number evaluates to NaN

edit: and yes, parseFloat is necessary too, otherwise the result will be a string instead of NaN

Answer (score 1):

```
var hoursString = "4.3|2.4|3.4|3.0|2.64|3.0|1.0|0.0|2.6|3.4|",
    hours = hoursString.split("|"),
    total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    total += parseFloat(hours[i]) || 0; // see explanation
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = total;
```

Why the `|| 0`? Because it checks if the string is `""`, if so the `||` operand will return the second value, in this case `0`.

This will output `25.740000000000002`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545015/can-someone-explain-this-0-2-0-1-0-30000000000000004) on the cause of the "wrong" result, and [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/xSFRU/) a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that each element in hours is still a string value even though it is written as a number. The easiest way to fix this would be to use javascripts parseFloat() function.

Example:

```
var hours=hoursString.split("|");

    var total=0;
    for (var i=0;i<hours.length;i++)
        {
        total += parseFloat(hours[i]);
        }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=total;
```

**EDIT:** Changed from `parseInt` to `parseFloat`

Comment: Sorry, try parseFloat(), since you are dealing with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hoursString = "4.3|2.4|3.4|3.0|2.64|3.0|1.0|0.0|2.6|3.4|"
var hours=hoursString.split("|");

var total=0;
var idx = 0;
for(idx in hours) {
    total += +hours[idx];
}

alert(total);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/tJ8sw/)