# Different booleans output at the same value=0 when starting from different values in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

#### Description of the issue:

Here is a (I hope reproducible) issue I encountered with a simple Python 3.6.7 function (on Ubuntu 18.04 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux):

```
def myfunc(x):
    while x < 0.2:
        y = x
        print("x: %.2f, y: %.2f: " % (x,y))
        print("Test: {}".format((x>=0 and x<=1 and y>=0 and y<=1)))
        x += 0.1
```

Then, when starting from -0.4:

```
myfunc(-0.4)
```

it returns:

```
x: -0.40, y: -0.40: 
Test: False
x: -0.30, y: -0.30: 
Test: False
x: -0.20, y: -0.20: 
Test: False
x: -0.10, y: -0.10: 
Test: False
x: -0.00, y: -0.00: 
Test: False
x: 0.10, y: 0.10: 
Test: True
x: 0.20, y: 0.20: 
Test: True
```

And when starting with -0.2:

```
myfunc(-0.2)
```

it returns:

```
x: -0.20, y: -0.20: 
Test: False
x: -0.10, y: -0.10: 
Test: False
x: 0.00, y: 0.00: 
Test: True
x: 0.10, y: 0.10: 
Test: True
```

The behavior at 0.00 is not the same (`False` when starting with `x=-0.4`, `True` when starting with `x=-0.2`).

This is obscure to me.
Do you know what phenomena happens here?

Comment: The problem is that neither 0.2 nor 0.1 can be exactly stored in memory as a float, they are approximated, and as you add them the tiny errors add up. There are many Stack Overflow questions on similar problems.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545015/can-someone-explain-this-0-2-0-1-0-30000000000000004

Comment: If you want to compare floating point numbers, you should check out numpy. i.e. 'numpy.isclose(.1+.2,.3)'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to the other Q/A. I then solved my issue by adding or subtracting a small epsilon value to my tests. :)