# Subtracting two decimal places in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to subtract two decimal places to a percentage of the difference, code below

Input

```
x = 0.0000034
y = 0.0000035

sum = (x-y)
print(sum)
print(sum * 100)
```

Output:

```
-9.999999999999989e-06
```

My desired output is:

```
0.001%
```

Why isn't the python code creating a simple answer like `-.000001`

Comment: Hey, you are running x - y, instead of y - x, first of all. Once you verify if my comment fixes the issue, perhaps consider deleting the question, as it seems to be based on simple human error.

Comment: I guess it's because of the way floating-point arithmetic works, which can introduce small errors in the calculations. Try to use `Decimal`. Something like this: `from decimal import Decimal` and then `x = Decimal('0.0000034')`. Check out this question, it may be connected with your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545015/can-someone-explain-this-0-2-0-1-0-30000000000000004

Comment: You can check here how decimal number is represented in float: https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Answer (score 0):

Floating point representation used by computers cannot represent all values exactly. In other words, a lot of values are stored as an approximation of the decimal value. Google "ieee 754". You can force a specific precision in the formatted output:

```
print("%.5f%%" % (sum * 100))
```

P.S., You presumably mean `sum = y - x`. Note that the parenthesis are not necessary in that expression. Also, using var name `sum` is confusing since you are calculating a difference.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I can't like the comment but thank you.