# Why does sqrt(4) - 2 equal -8.1648465955514287168521180122928e-39 when using the windows calculator?

Tags: math, floating-point, calculator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is floating point stored? When does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter)

Using the built-in calculator on my Win7 x64 I get the number `-8.1648465955514287168521180122928e-39` when calculation `sqrt(4)-2`.

I would expect the result to be 0.

Comment: What's to round with `sqrt(4)-2`?

Comment: How do you think the sqrt(4) gets evaluated?

Comment: @Mysticial: decidedly non-standard floating-point error; any *standard* floating-point system would produce 0.

Comment: @StephenCanon Whatever Windows is doing, it's not standard since that's a lot more than double-precision. Perhaps it's emulating quad-precision, but not perfectly.

Comment: My understanding is that Calculator guys implemented a high-precision floating point library so that they didn't get embarassing errors... like this :)

Comment: @dlev - indeed they did http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/25/141253.aspx

Comment: @dlev: it would seem they didn't do a very good job of it, since this is computed correctly in every standardized floating-point system =)

Comment: @StephenCanon Could you elaborate? I would have thought that the presence (or absence) of representation error would be based on the algorithm used to calculate the square-root.

Comment: @JB King I don't know how the windows calculator evaluates sqrt(4). Intuitively I thought it doesn't involve fractions that would introduce rounding error.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Approximations_that_depend_on_IEEE_representation has a few computations that do involve fractions.  You may want to consider researching Numerical Analysis versus Symbolic Computation just as something to consider if you want to keep going down this rabbit hole.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/09/26b.html would be Jel's explaining of an Excel bug that is a similar point.

Comment: @dlev: In every standard floating-point system, modest integers are represented exactly, and square root and subtraction are correctly-rounded operations, which leaves no possible source of error.

Comment: @StephenCanon Ah, I see. You're including how certain operations are performed in the definition. Makes sense, and agreed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some error with floating-point values, when you go to subtract them on occasion.  You may get a representation that's 0 or really close to 0 (10^-39's pretty close).

For more information, check out [Fractions in Binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how fractions were represented in binary. This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) helped as well.