# Why does 65.6*100%10 equals to 9, instead of 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, math

```
echo 65.7 * 100 % 10 // 0

echo 65.6 * 100 % 10 // 9 <---

echo 6560 % 10       // 0

echo 65.5 * 100 % 10 // 0
```

Can someone please explain why?

**EDIT:**

for human or non-programmers, the result 9 is apprently wrong.

how can I prevent this `"error"` when programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `65.6` in floating point is actually an approximation of `65.6`. It is actually marginally less than `65.6`, i.e. `65.5999` or similar.

Assuming my wild guess at the actual value is correct, you have `6559.9`, which is [stripped to `6599`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) by the modulus operator, then divided by 10 for remainder 9.

Answer (score 3):

Because 65.6 * 100 is 6559.9999999999.

That's [floating points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter) for you.

Comment: so how can I get the actual 6559.9999999999 in php?

Comment: You cannot get all decimal numbers in a binary floating point system. Some of them (like 65.6) just cannot get represented.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, this has to do with floating point arithmetic. I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
<?php

echo (65.7 * 100 == 6570) ? "Equal" : "Not equal";  // Equal
echo (65.6 * 100 == 6560) ? "Equal" : "Not equal";  // NOT EQUAL !!
echo (65.5 * 100 == 6550) ? "Equal" : "Not equal";  // Equal

?>
```

65.6 * 100 is **NOT** 6560. The [big red warning box here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) explains why.