# Big float numbers weird results

Tags: java, floating-accuracy

In java I am using float to store the numbers. I chose the float format as I am working both with integers and double numbers, where the numbers are different, there can be big integers or big double numbers with different number of decimals. But when I insert these numbers into database, the wrong number is stored. For example:

`float value = 0f;
value = 67522665;
System.out.println(value);`

Printed: 6.7522664E7 and it is stored in the database as 67522664  not as 67522665

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" before doing anything serious involving floating point numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Floating point numbers have limited resolution — roughly 7 significant digits. You are seeing round-off error. You can use a `double` for more resolution or, for exact arithmetic, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Suggested reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: By the way, `BigDecimal` calculation is much slower than other primitive data type.

Comment: @Drogba - Yes, indeed. But if you need the accuracy, that's the price you need to pay.

Comment: Limited precision, not accuracy.

Comment: @yshavit - You're right that "accuracy" wasn't the right word. But "precision" isn't right either, since that has to do with repeatability. (IEEE floating point calculations are completely repeatable.) I went with "resolution".

Comment: The problem is the type of the column in the database where I am inserting this value, is float.

Comment: @TedHopp Precision is a pretty standard term in this regard. It's the one used in [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3), for instance, and the docs for BigDecimal start out with defining it as an "arbitrary precision" number. Heck, it's the term used in the very article you linked to.

Comment: @yshavit - The article I link to in my answer does indeed talk about precision in terms of number of bits. It also talks about "numerical accuracy", "10 digits of accuracy", etc. As far as I can tell, there is no uniformly accepted definition for these terms in computer science. (Lots of definitions, but lots of disagreement.) In terms of real standards, the [International Vocabulary of Metrology](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_200_2012.pdf) published by the BIPM has nice definitions for accuracy, precision, and resolution. It's worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

Doubles and floats have storage issues.
[How is floating point stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter)

"The float and double types are designed primarily for scientific and engineering
calculations. They perform binary floating-point arithmetic, which was carefully
designed to furnish accurate approximations quickly over a broad range of magnitudes.
They do not, however, provide exact results and should not be used where
exact results are required."

Don't use float. Use **BigDecimal** instead. And in my experience with databases, they return their NUMBER-typed elements as BigDecimal. When I fetch them using JDBC, they are BigDecimal objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got it, this is about the **gap size** (or [ULP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), *units in the last place*) in the binary representation, that is the spacing between contiguous f-point values.

This value is equal to:

```
2^(e+1-p)
```

being *e* the actual *exponent* of a number, and *p* the *precision*.

Note that the spacing (or gap) increases as the value of the represented number increases:

[image]

In IEEE-754, the precision is *p* 24, so you can see that when *e >= 23* we can start talking of integer spacing in the floating point world.

```
2^23 = 8388608   --> 8388608 actually stored IEEE-754
       8388608.2 --> 8388608 actually stored IEEE-754
```

Things get worse as numbers get bigger. For example:

```
164415560 --> 164415552 actually stored IEEE-754
```

---

<sub>Ref: [***The Spacing of Binary Floating-Point Numbers***](https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-spacing-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/)</sub>