# Expr for float values in TCL

Tags: tcl

Calculating float values

```
tclsh
% expr 0.2+0.2
0.4
% expr 0.2+0.1
0.30000000000000004
%
```

Why not 0.3??

Am i missing some thing.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic. This is the classic example of what could get wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is floating point stored? When does it matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither 0.1 or 0.2 have an exact representation in IEEE double precision binary floating point arithmetic (which Tcl uses internally for expressions involving fractional values, as there's good hardware support for them). This means that the values you are computing with are never *exactly* what you think they are; instead, they're both very slightly more (as it happens; they could also have been slightly less in general). When you add 0.2+ε<sub>1</sub>+0.1+ε<sub>2</sub>, it can happen that ε<sub>1</sub>+ε<sub>2</sub> can add up to more than the threshold where 0.3 (another imprecisely represented value) becomes the next exactly represented value above it. This is what you have observed. It's also inherent in the way floating point mathematics works in a vast array of languages; only integer arithmetic (or fractional arithmetic capable of being expressed as exact multiples of some power of 2, e.g., 0.5, 0.25, 0.125) is guaranteed to be exact.

The only interesting thing of note here is that Tcl 8.5 and 8.6 prefer to *render* floating point numbers with the minimal number of digits required to get the exact value back when re-parsed. If you want to get a fixed number of digits (e.g., 8) try using `format` when converting:

```
format %.8f [expr 0.2+0.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior exists in almost all programming languages, e.g. Ruby, Python, etc.

The suggestion here is try to avoid storing numbers in floating points, use integer whenever possible. The bottom line is do not use floating points in a comparison.

Comment: “avoid storing numbers in floating point”? I should keep a rubber duck in them instead? Or a cool beer?

Comment: @DonalFellows Just different ways of handling the issue. To store a number with fixed number of digits (e.g. 2), instead of using `format` to keep it at 12.34, I'd rather store it as 1234 and also keep the number of digits (i.e. 2) in a complementary variable. But again, this is intended for any number that might be used for comparison. We still need the power of floating numbers to do maths.

Comment: you always have such problems. 1/7 + 2/7 = 3/7. But you probably get a rounding error somewhere on the way.