# Small number treated as zero when adding in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am writing a code for a Monte Carlo simulation in Fortran, but I am having a lot of problems because of the small numbers involved.

The biggest problem is that in my code particle positions are not updated; the incriminated code looks like this

```
x=x+step*cos(p)*sin(t)
```

with `step=0.001`. With this, the code won't update the position and I get a infinite loop because the particle never exits the region. If I modify my code with something like this:

```
 x=x+step
```

or

```
x=x+step*cos(t)
```

there is no problem. So it seems that the product `step*cos(t)*cos(p)`(of the order 10**-4) is too small and is treated as zero.

`x` is of the order 10**4.

How do I solve this problem in portable way?

My compiler is the latest f95.

Comment: Please give details of the values of the variables and their declarations.  You don't care so much the magnitude of `y` in `x=x+y` but its size in comparison with the spacing around `x`.  Without further details we can't be more precise.

Comment: @francescalus `x` is of the order 10**4. I have edited the post.

Comment: You are probably adding a tiny number of less than 1e-4 to a single precision real of size 1e4. This is similar to a human able to remember maximum 3 digits of a number and he adds 10 together with 0.000001. since he only can remember 3 digits, the result stays 10.

Comment: Here it is not important, but next time it might be. f95 does not specify any particular compiler or its specific version. We can only guess that you are in fact using gfortran on Ubuntu Linux or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is essentially the one of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56947/3157076).  However, it's useful to add some Fortran-specific comments.

As in that other question, the discrete nature of floating point numbers mean that there is a point where one number is too small to make a difference when added to another.  In the case of this question:

```
if (1e4+1e-4==1e4) print *, "Oh?"
if (1d4+1d-4==1d4) print *, "Really?"
end
```

That is, you may be able to use double precision reals and you'll see the problem go away.

What is the smallest number you can add to `1e4` to get something different from `1e4` (or to `1d4`)?

```
print *, 1e4 + SPACING(1e4), 1e4+SPACING(1e4)/2
print *, 1d4 + SPACING(1d4), 1d4+SPACING(1d4)/2
end
```

This *spacing* varies with the size of the number.  For large numbers it is large and around 1 it is small.

```
print*, EPSILON(1e0), SPACING([(1e2**i,i=0,5)])
print*, EPSILON(1d0), SPACING([(1d2**i,i=0,5)])
end
```