# Why is double x * double x not equal to int y

Tags: c#, loops, console

I am into this code but I need an explanation as to why

```
            int n = 6;
            int count = 0;
            double end = Math.Sqrt(n);
            for (int i = 1; i < end; i++)
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                    count += 2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(end * end + " - " + n);
            Console.WriteLine(end * end == n);
            if (end * end == 6)  
                Console.WriteLine("why");
```

returns `false` in the second `Console.Writeline` but if `n=9` returns `true`

Comment: Comparing floating point values for equality doesn't work that way. See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=netframework-4.8 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp

Comment: `end * end = 5.9999999999999991`.

Comment: @AFriend the first `Console.Writeline` shows the value of `end * end` together with `n`

Comment: Mostly likely a fitting duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net) similar questions are asked every couple of days

Comment: [Fiddling](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8a59Gl) around your example, try with `9`..

Answer (score 0):

`end` is a double and is equal to the square root of 6. Even though `end * end` is supposed to be 6, you are comparing `double` to `int` with the `=` sign which is a big no-no.
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650091/whats-the-best-way-to-compare-double-and-int) answer you can see the correct way to do so.

Comment: Yea, I know I am comparing double to int but how come if I use `n = 9` it will return `true`?