# How can I print the greatest number of two number without any conditional statements?

Tags: c#

The greatest of two numbers without any conditional statements. I need to get two numbers from the user and find out the greatest of them but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can use [`Math.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to compare Double and Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650091/whats-the-best-way-to-compare-double-and-int)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this but I would solve this by sorting numbers in a descending way. Try this:

```
int[] numbers = { 10, 20};
Array.Sort(numbers);
Array.Reverse(numbers);
Console.WriteLine("The highest number is: " + numbers[0]);
```

Or, just use `numbers.Max()` instead of `Array.Sort(numbers)` and `Array.Reverse(numbers)`. There are still more than 20 ways to solve this problem.

Comment: This does not sort the array, it just reverses the order.

Comment: I forgot to add `Array.Sort(numbers);`. Now it works.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but your array is only two numbers and you are sorting it, why do you need to reverse it? You know that the last element will contain the largest number...

Comment: `Array.Sort(numbers)` sorts in a ascending way like 1, 45, 67, 22, 88, ..., and reverse them to get the highest number in the first position of the array. This code is useful if he is using more than two numbers.

Comment: I tested the code with `int[] numbers = {12, 45, 34, 99, 3, 95, 34, 1, 2, 3, 5};` and got 99. It works. But if he is using two numbers, code still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Max, but it is a wrapper around a ternary statement that looks like this:

```
return (val1>=val2)?val1:val2;
```

There is a different way...

```
var array = new double[] { userValue1, userValue2 };
var largest = array.Max();
```

Or you can sort the array in descending order and get the first element... Really though all programming boils down to a conditional somewhere, and `.Max()` is no different, it just sorts the array and gets the biggest value.