# Test if two lines intersect - JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, intersection, line-intersection

I've tried searching for a javascript function that will detect if two lines intersect each other.

The function will take the x,y values of both the start end points for each line (we'll call them line A and line B).

Is to return true if they intersect, otherwise false.

Example of the function. I'm happy if the answer uses a vector object instead.

```
Function isIntersect (lineAp1x, lineAp1y, lineAp2x, lineAp2y, lineBp1x, lineBp1y, lineBp2x, lineBp2y) 
{

    // JavaScript line intersecting test here. 

}
```

Some background info: this code is for a game I'm trying to make in html5 canvas, and is part of my collision detection.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about school math

Comment: @Nakilon Yes... or collision detection algorithm for game development.

Comment: @Nakilon - since when does high school math cover normalisation of equations to reduce computational overhead? Jarrod may not have explicitly asked for this, but it is implicit in the use-case he presents. (My answer is directly equivalent to the accepted one, it is simply better optimised.)

Comment: There's a new best answer but the scores don't yet reflect that. Scroll down for Dan Fox's code, which is elegant, concise and likely to be even faster than mine. It _does_ need tweaking to damp floating point errors. If you need a sample for that, also look at my answer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
// returns true if the line from (a,b)->(c,d) intersects with (p,q)->(r,s)
function intersects(a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s) {
  var det, gamma, lambda;
  det = (c - a) * (s - q) - (r - p) * (d - b);
  if (det === 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    lambda = ((s - q) * (r - a) + (p - r) * (s - b)) / det;
    gamma = ((b - d) * (r - a) + (c - a) * (s - b)) / det;
    return (0 < lambda && lambda < 1) && (0 < gamma && gamma < 1);
  }
};
```

**Explanation: (vectors, a matrix and a cheeky determinant)**

Lines can be described by some initial vector, v, and a direction vector, d:

```
r = v + lambda*d
```

We use one point `(a,b)` as the initial vector and the difference between them `(c-a,d-b)` as the direction vector. Likewise for our second line.

If our two lines intersect, then there must be a point, X, that is reachable by travelling some distance, lambda, along our first line and also reachable by travelling gamma units along our second line.  This gives us two simultaneous equations for the coordinates of X:

```
X = v1 + lambda*d1 
X = v2 + gamma *d2
```

These equations can be represented in matrix form. We check that the determinant is non-zero to see if the intersection X even exists.

If there is an intersection, then we must check that the intersection actually lies between both sets of points.  If lambda is greater than 1, the intersection is beyond the second point.  If lambda is less than 0, the intersection is before the first point.

Hence, `0<lambda<1 && 0<gamma<1` indicates that the two lines intersect!

Comment: Be carefull: if the determinant is zero, it means that the two lines are parallel. Either they are equal (and all points are "intersection points") or "strictly" parallel (and no intersection).

Comment: Oh my, that is _elegant_.

Comment: a slightly looser `if` check of `((-0.01 < lambda && lambda < 1.01) && (-0.01 < gamma && gamma < 1.01))` also detects lines that "appear" to intersect when rendered to HTML canvas (close enough to count in my particular use case)

Comment: e.g. for above comment ^ with `a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s` of `-10347270, 5119881, -10347300, 5119880, -10347268, 5119874, -10347277, 5119906`, lambda would be `-0.0010319917440660474` but lines appear to just barely touch

Comment: There is something wrong with this code. When I set a,b,c,d=0,0,0,1 and p,q,r,s=0,0.5,2,0.5 then lambda=0.5 (correct) and gamma=1(wrong, must be zero)!

Comment: Yes, gamma is the opposite of what it should be according to the original explanation. `lambda` is correctly the percent distance along the first line from `(a,b)` to `(c,d)`, but `gamma` is the percent distance **back** from `(r,s)` to `(p,q)`

Comment: @jacob that feels kind of dirty. If you want to detect touches, why not use equal or operators (>= and <=)

Comment: @Sventies With floating point, equality is misleading and should not really be used. Margins are better.

Comment: @akauppi because of floating point rounding errors?

Comment: @Sventies yes, check eg here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison . Be in touch directly if you want to check more - let's not make this into a discussion. :)

Comment: Here's a **compressed** version of the this answer: `function intersects(a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s){var γ,λ,=(c-a)*(s-q)-(r-p)*(d-b);return 0!==&&(γ=((b-d)*(r-a)+(c-a)*(s-b))/,0<(λ=((s-q)*(r-a)+(p-r)*(s-b))/)&&λ<1&&0<γ&&γ<1)}`

Comment: @oliverpool Can you propose a solution if the lines are parallel or intersect

Answer (score 43):

Peter Wone's answer is a great solution, but it lacks an explanation. I spent the last hour or so understanding how it works and think I understand enough to explain it as well. See his answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725715/697477

I've also included a solution for the co-linear lines in the code below.

## Using Rotational Directions to check for intersection

To explain the answer, let's look at something common about every intersection of two lines. Given the picture below, we can see that ***P<sub>1</sub>*** to ***IP*** to ***P<sub>4</sub>*** rotates counter clockwise. We can see that it's complimentary sides rotate clockwise. Now, we don't know if it intersects, so we don't know the intersection point. But we can also see that ***P<sub>1</sub>*** to ***P<sub>2</sub>*** to ***P<sub>4</sub>*** also rotates counter clockwise. Additionally, ***P<sub>1</sub>*** to ***P<sub>2</sub>*** to ***P<sub>3</sub>*** rotates clock wise. We can use this knowledge to determine whether two lines intersect or not.

[image: Stretching the face]

## Intersection Example

[image: Line intersection] [image: Line Intersection]

You'll notice that intersecting lines create four faces that point opposite directions. Since they face opposite directions, we know that the direction of ***P<sub>1</sub>*** to ***P<sub>2</sub>*** to ***P<sub>3</sub>*** rotates a direction different than ***P<sub>1</sub>*** to ***P<sub>2</sub>*** to ***P<sub>4</sub>***. We also know that ***P<sub>1</sub>*** to ***P<sub>3</sub>*** to ***P<sub>4</sub>*** rotates a different direction than ***P<sub>2</sub>*** to ***P<sub>3</sub>*** to ***P<sub>4</sub>***.

## Non-Intersection Example

[image: Line No Intersection]
[image: Line No Intersection]

In this example, you should notice that following the same pattern for the intersection test, the two faces rotate the same direction. Since they face the same direction, we know that they do not intersect.

## Code Sample

So, we can implement this into the original code supplied by Peter Wone.

```js
// Check the direction these three points rotate
function RotationDirection(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y) {
  if (((p3y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x)) > ((p2y - p1y) * (p3x - p1x)))
    return 1;
  else if (((p3y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x)) == ((p2y - p1y) * (p3x - p1x)))
    return 0;
  
  return -1;
}

function containsSegment(x1, y1, x2, y2, sx, sy) {
  if (x1 < x2 && x1 < sx && sx < x2) return true;
  else if (x2 < x1 && x2 < sx && sx < x1) return true;
  else if (y1 < y2 && y1 < sy && sy < y2) return true;
  else if (y2 < y1 && y2 < sy && sy < y1) return true;
  else if (x1 == sx && y1 == sy || x2 == sx && y2 == sy) return true;
  return false;
}

function hasIntersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
  var f1 = RotationDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4);
  var f2 = RotationDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  var f3 = RotationDirection(x1, y1, x3, y3, x4, y4);
  var f4 = RotationDirection(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4);
  
  // If the faces rotate opposite directions, they intersect.
  var intersect = f1 != f2 && f3 != f4;
  
  // If the segments are on the same line, we have to check for overlap.
  if (f1 == 0 && f2 == 0 && f3 == 0 && f4 == 0) {
    intersect = containsSegment(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) || containsSegment(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4) ||
    containsSegment(x3, y3, x4, y4, x1, y1) || containsSegment(x3, y3, x4, y4, x2, y2);
  }
  
  return intersect;
}

// Main call for checking intersection. Particularly verbose for explanation purposes.
function checkIntersection() {
  // Grab the values
  var x1 = parseInt($('#p1x').val());
  var y1 = parseInt($('#p1y').val());
  var x2 = parseInt($('#p2x').val());
  var y2 = parseInt($('#p2y').val());
  var x3 = parseInt($('#p3x').val());
  var y3 = parseInt($('#p3y').val());
  var x4 = parseInt($('#p4x').val());
  var y4 = parseInt($('#p4y').val());

  // Determine the direction they rotate. (You can combine this all into one step.)
  var face1CounterClockwise = RotationDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4);
  var face2CounterClockwise = RotationDirection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  var face3CounterClockwise = RotationDirection(x1, y1, x3, y3, x4, y4);
  var face4CounterClockwise = RotationDirection(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4);

  // If face 1 and face 2 rotate different directions and face 3 and face 4 rotate different directions, 
  // then the lines intersect.
  var intersect = hasIntersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4);

  // Output the results.
  var output = "Face 1 (P1, P2, P4) Rotates: " + ((face1CounterClockwise > 0) ? "counterClockWise" : ((face1CounterClockwise == 0) ? "Linear" : "clockwise")) + "<br />";
  var output = output + "Face 2 (P1, P2, P3) Rotates: " + ((face2CounterClockwise > 0) ? "counterClockWise" : ((face2CounterClockwise == 0) ? "Linear" : "clockwise")) + "<br />";
  var output = output + "Face 3 (P1, P3, P4) Rotates: " + ((face3CounterClockwise > 0) ? "counterClockWise" : ((face3CounterClockwise == 0) ? "Linear" : "clockwise")) + "<br />";
  var output = output + "Face 4 (P2, P3, P4) Rotates: " + ((face4CounterClockwise > 0) ? "counterClockWise" : ((face4CounterClockwise == 0) ? "Linear" : "clockwise")) + "<br />";
  var output = output + "Intersection: " + ((intersect) ? "Yes" : "No") + "<br />";
  $('#result').html(output);


  // Draw the lines.
  var canvas = $("#canvas");
  var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.get(0).width, canvas.get(0).height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.moveTo(x3, y3);
  context.lineTo(x4, y4);
  context.stroke();
}

checkIntersection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="border: 2px solid #000000; float: right;"></canvas>
<div style="float: left;">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <b>Line 1:</b>
    <br />P1 x:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p1x" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="0">y:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p1y" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="20">
    <br />P2 x:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p2x" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="100">y:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p2y" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="20">
    <br />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <b>Line 2:</b>
    <br />P3 x:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p3x" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="150">y:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p3y" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="100">
    <br />P4 x:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p4x" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="0">y:
    <input type="number" min="0" max="200" id="p4y" style="width: 40px;" onChange="checkIntersection();" value="0">
    <br />
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both;" />
  <br />
  <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; padding: 2px;" id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @msc87 I don't see any reason it wouldn't. Easiest way to find out is to try it. Take the above code sample and plug decimal values into it.

Comment: Well, actually I tried it but I am not sure if it's my code or the method. I snap to a point on a line and then use turf.js to find intersections. It sometimes finds the intersection and sometimes can't. Seems the problem to be with the float numbers as I see your code here can easily detect even the lines that touch each other.

Comment: In other words, my lines may not intersect as the float numbers' precision may vary time to time.

Comment: @msc87 - the classic solution is epsilon comparison. Instead of a==b use Math.abs(a-b) < epsilon. For explanation and a suggested epsilon value read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @msc87 - if (a > b + Number.EPSILON) return 1 else if (a + Number.EPSILON < b) return -1 else return 0;

Comment: If you put in the lines: P1 (14,11) P2 (14,12) P3 (14,39) P4 (14,38) or P1 (20, 33) P2 (21, 32) P3 (14, 39) P4 (19, 34) you get a wrong answer. Do you know why?

Comment: I found out there is a check missing. If the linesegments are part of the same line (all faces = 0) you need to check if they overlap. Fx: if (face1CounterClockwise === 0 && face2CounterClockwise === 0
            && face3CounterClockwise === 0 && face4CounterClockwise === 0) {
            intersect = line1.hasPoint(line2.point1) || line1.hasPoint(line2.point2);
        }

Comment: @LongInt Good catch. Your solution needs to consider the possibility that line segment 2 could completely contain line segment 1. I updated the answer with a check for two segments on the same line.

Answer (score 33):

```
function lineIntersect(x1,y1,x2,y2, x3,y3,x4,y4) {
    var x=((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4));
    var y=((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4));
    if (isNaN(x)||isNaN(y)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (x1>=x2) {
            if (!(x2<=x&&x<=x1)) {return false;}
        } else {
            if (!(x1<=x&&x<=x2)) {return false;}
        }
        if (y1>=y2) {
            if (!(y2<=y&&y<=y1)) {return false;}
        } else {
            if (!(y1<=y&&y<=y2)) {return false;}
        }
        if (x3>=x4) {
            if (!(x4<=x&&x<=x3)) {return false;}
        } else {
            if (!(x3<=x&&x<=x4)) {return false;}
        }
        if (y3>=y4) {
            if (!(y4<=y&&y<=y3)) {return false;}
        } else {
            if (!(y3<=y&&y<=y4)) {return false;}
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection#Mathematics) page I found the answer from.

Comment: Caution: This function fails to recognize an intersection where one indeed exists for the following arguments: "67.1999999998311, 80.0499999999588, 5.351339640030417, 1102.1804922619292, 55.24999999990314, 141.54999999989604, 71.24999999990314, 141.54999999989604" ...

Here's a function which seems to be more reliable: 
https://gist.github.com/Joncom/e8e8d18ebe7fe55c3894

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add/subtract a tiny epsilon to deal with floating point inaccuracy for horizontal/vertical lines where e.g. `x1===x2`.  (I needed the coordinates so I couldn't use the @Joncom version.) https://gist.github.com/gordonwoodhull/50eb65d2f048789f9558

Answer (score 26):

Although it is useful to be able to find the intersection point, testing for *whether* line segments intersect is most often used for polygon hit-testing, and given the usual applications of that, you need to do it *fast*. Therefore I suggest you do it like this, using only subtraction, multiplication, comparison and AND. `Turn` computes the direction of the change in slope between the two edges described by the three points: 1 means counter-clockwise, 0 means no turn and -1 means clockwise.

This code expects points expressed as GLatLng objects but can be trivially rewritten to other systems of representation. The slope comparison has been normalised to [epsilon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) tolerance to damp floating point errors.

```
function Turn(p1, p2, p3) {
  a = p1.lng(); b = p1.lat(); 
  c = p2.lng(); d = p2.lat();
  e = p3.lng(); f = p3.lat();
  A = (f - b) * (c - a);
  B = (d - b) * (e - a);
  return (A > B + Number.EPSILON) ? 1 : (A + Number.EPSILON < B) ? -1 : 0;
}

function isIntersect(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
  return (Turn(p1, p3, p4) != Turn(p2, p3, p4)) && (Turn(p1, p2, p3) != Turn(p1, p2, p4));
}
```

Comment: This seems to work great but I don't really follow why it works. A link with some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen when the segments are co-linear. Perhaps you can check and enlighten me.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed easy to see it after drawing some lines. If my math is right this wouldn't handle co-linear cases, since the CCW test is basically testing the cross product AxB > 0. Given that AxB will be 0 for the co-linear case it will return false every time. I tested with some simple co-linear cases and verified isIntersect returns false, although this would be up to the float precision for non-simple cases i guess.

Comment: CCW returning false for co-linearity is logically correct because the turn isn't counter-clockwise. The flaw in the method is use of a Boolean in tri-state logic. Implicit in this implementation is the notion that if the lines are co-linear, they do not cross. This is entirely in accordance with a common Euclidean definition of parallel lines as lines that do not cross; these are two line segments that do not cross, the perpendicular distance between the segments being 0.

Comment: If it's so trivial to rewrite your example without using some obscure, bespoke data structure, why did you elect to use `GLatLng` instead of simple `x,y` coordinates?

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions - because (a) I didn't feel like it, (b) cut and paste from working code does not introduce translation errors, (c) the Google Maps API is hardly obscure, and (d) anyone too thick to mentally translate will not understand the answer anyway.

Comment: If you think it matters, change it yourself instead of carping at me. No-one else has cared in two years and many have found it a useful answer.

Comment: **Caution: this function fails in some cases.** 1) It fails to detect when one line segment is inside another. 2) It fails to detect when second line segment starts where first one ends. 3) It fails when second line segment ends inside the first line segment at a right angle. Below are test points (Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, Dx, Dy): 5, 10,  5,  0,  5,  4,  5,  5 ; 5,  5,  5,  0,  5, 10,  5,  5 ; 0,  0, 10, 10, 10,  0,  5,  5

Comment: @Ignas2526, whether that is a failure is arguable. To *intersect* the segments must *cross*. These are all edge cases, we actually discussed your case 1, and whether any of these cases meet a strict definition of intersection depends on the definition. For the purpose of hit detection these cases are irrelevant because in the next iteration of any system involving motion, real or simulated, the very specialised preconditions will cease to be. Special case handling is therefore a performance sacrifice with no payoff.

Comment: @Ignas2526 Consider collision detection: real collisions involve deformation, elastic or plastic. At the moment your cases describe this is *about* to occur but has yet to actually *happen*. It's only in the *next* iteration that the bodies affect one another. Whether a video game or a simulation of reality, these cases are no more a concern than the failure of division when the divisor is zero.

Comment: this didn't work for me. the order of the p1,p2,p3,p4 are L1_a, L1_b, L2_a, L2_b, right?

Comment: I haven't looked at this code for nearly 20 years. Other answers discuss my answer in depth complete with pretty diagrams.

Answer (score 12):

I've rewritten Peter Wone's answer to a single function using x/y instead of lat()/long()

```
function isIntersecting(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    function CCW(p1, p2, p3) {
        return (p3.y - p1.y) * (p2.x - p1.x) > (p2.y - p1.y) * (p3.x - p1.x);
    }
    return (CCW(p1, p3, p4) != CCW(p2, p3, p4)) && (CCW(p1, p2, p3) != CCW(p1, p2, p4));
}
```

Comment: Johnathan's function, minified: `function isIntersecting(n,t,r,e){function i(n,t,r){return(r.y-n.y)*(t.x-n.x)>(t.y-n.y)*(r.x-n.x)}return i(n,r,e)!=i(t,r,e)&&i(n,t,r)!=i(n,t,e)}`

Comment: Does this assume that +x is left and +y is up? Not sure what to change when +x is right and +y is down.

Comment: @Solo: Draw your intersecting/non-intersecting lines on a piece of paper. Hold that paper up to a mirror and look a the reflection. Does reflecting the drawing cause two intersecting line segments on the paper to separate in the mirror image? Or does it cause two non-intersecting lines on the paper to cross in the mirror image? If not, then intersection is insensitive to flipping of the coordinate system.

Answer (score 7):

Here comes a TypeScript implementation, heavily inspired by Dan Fox's solution.
This implementation will give you the intersection point, if there is one. Otherwise (parallel or no intersection), `undefined` will be returned.

```js
interface Point2D {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function intersection(from1: Point2D, to1: Point2D, from2: Point2D, to2: Point2D): Point2D {
  const dX: number = to1.x - from1.x;
  const dY: number = to1.y - from1.y;

  const determinant: number = dX * (to2.y - from2.y) - (to2.x - from2.x) * dY;
  if (determinant === 0) return undefined; // parallel lines

  const lambda: number = ((to2.y - from2.y) * (to2.x - from1.x) + (from2.x - to2.x) * (to2.y - from1.y)) / determinant;
  const gamma: number = ((from1.y - to1.y) * (to2.x - from1.x) + dX * (to2.y - from1.y)) / determinant;

  // check if there is an intersection
  if (!(0 <= lambda && lambda <= 1) || !(0 <= gamma && gamma <= 1)) return undefined;

  return {
    x: from1.x + lambda * dX,
    y: from1.y + lambda * dY,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Joncom/e8e8d18ebe7fe55c3894) with some more concise variable names, and some Coffee.

### JavaScript version

```
var lineSegmentsIntersect = (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)=> {
    var a_dx = x2 - x1;
    var a_dy = y2 - y1;
    var b_dx = x4 - x3;
    var b_dy = y4 - y3;
    var s = (-a_dy * (x1 - x3) + a_dx * (y1 - y3)) / (-b_dx * a_dy + a_dx * b_dy);
    var t = (+b_dx * (y1 - y3) - b_dy * (x1 - x3)) / (-b_dx * a_dy + a_dx * b_dy);
    return (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1);
}
```

### CoffeeScript version

```
lineSegmentsIntersect = (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)->
    a_dx = x2 - x1
    a_dy = y2 - y1
    b_dx = x4 - x3
    b_dy = y4 - y3
    s = (-a_dy * (x1 - x3) + a_dx * (y1 - y3)) / (-b_dx * a_dy + a_dx * b_dy)
    t = (+b_dx * (y1 - y3) - b_dy * (x1 - x3)) / (-b_dx * a_dy + a_dx * b_dy)
    (0 <= s <= 1 and 0 <= t <= 1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for lineSegmentsIntersect(2, 0, 2, 6, 2, 8, 2, 3)

Answer (score 3):

First, find intersection coordinates - here it's described in detail:
http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html

Then check if the x-coordinate for intersection falls within the x ranges for one of the lines (or do the same with y-coordinate, if you prefer), 
i.e. if xIntersection is between lineAp1x and lineAp2x, then they intersect.

Answer (score 0):

For all folks who would like to have a solutions ready for coldfusion, here is what I adapted from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/awt/geom/Line2D.java#Line2D.linesIntersect%28double%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%29

the imporants functions are ccw and linesIntersect from java.awt.geom.Line2D and I wrote them into coldfusion, so here we go:

```
<cffunction name="relativeCCW" description="schnittpunkt der vier punkte (2 geraden) berechnen">
<!---
Returns an indicator of where the specified point (px,py) lies with respect to this line segment. See the method comments of relativeCCW(double,double,double,double,double,double) to interpret the return value.
Parameters:
px the X coordinate of the specified point to be compared with this Line2D
py the Y coordinate of the specified point to be compared with this Line2D
Returns:
an integer that indicates the position of the specified coordinates with respect to this Line2D
--->
<cfargument name="x1" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="y1" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="x2" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="y2" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="px" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="py" type="numeric" required="yes">
    <cfscript>
    x2 = x2 - x1;
    y2 = y2 - y1;
    px = px - x1;
    py = py - y1;
    ccw = (px * y2) - (py * x2);
    if (ccw EQ 0) {
        // The point is colinear, classify based on which side of
        // the segment the point falls on.  We can calculate a
        // relative value using the projection of px,py onto the
        // segment - a negative value indicates the point projects
        // outside of the segment in the direction of the particular
        // endpoint used as the origin for the projection.
        ccw = (px * x2) + (py * y2);
        if (ccw GT 0) {
            // Reverse the projection to be relative to the original x2,y2
            // x2 and y2 are simply negated.
            // px and py need to have (x2 - x1) or (y2 - y1) subtracted
            //    from them (based on the original values)
            // Since we really want to get a positive answer when the
             //    point is "beyond (x2,y2)", then we want to calculate
            //    the inverse anyway - thus we leave x2 & y2 negated.       
            px = px - x2;
            py = py - y2;
            ccw = (px * x2) + (py * y2);
            if (ccw LT 0) {
                ccw = 0;
                }
        }
    }
    if (ccw LT 0) {
        ret = -1;
    }
    else if (ccw GT 0) {
        ret = 1;
    }
    else {
        ret = 0;
    }   
    </cfscript> 
    <cfreturn ret>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="linesIntersect" description="schnittpunkt der vier punkte (2 geraden) berechnen">
<cfargument name="x1" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="y1" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="x2" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="y2" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="x3" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="y3" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="x4" type="numeric" required="yes" >
<cfargument name="y4" type="numeric" required="yes">
    <cfscript>
    a1 = relativeCCW(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    a2 = relativeCCW(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4);
    a3 = relativeCCW(x3, y3, x4, y4, x1, y1);
    a4 = relativeCCW(x3, y3, x4, y4, x2, y2);
    aa = ((relativeCCW(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) * relativeCCW(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4) LTE 0)
            && (relativeCCW(x3, y3, x4, y4, x1, y1) * relativeCCW(x3, y3, x4, y4, x2, y2) LTE 0));
    </cfscript>
 <cfreturn aa>
</cffunction>
```

I hope this can help for adapting to other laguages?

Answer (score -3):

Use the pythageorum theorum to find the distance between the 2 objects and add the radius [Pythageorum Theorum Distance Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um98j.jpg)