# Detect edge crossing in vis.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, directed-graph, vis.js

Is there a way to detect if edges cross each other in vis.js graph-2d?
I am trying to layout a directed graph with the Sugiyama algorithm, but its a little bit tricky. Is there an available Javascript implementation/tutorial of that algorithm or the edge-crossing?
I have seen many papers with pseudo-code and very specific implementations but they aren't very helpful for me.

Comment: At every moment redraw the graph you can cycle through all the pairs of edges and determine which of them intersect. What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if two lines intersect - JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043805/test-if-two-lines-intersect-javascript-function)