# Check if a line drawn intersects or inside the existing polygon on html canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, math, canvas, geometry

Check if a line drawn intersects or inside the existing polygon on html canvas.

I have a html canvas and there is polygon (mainly quadrilateral)  which is already drawn. Now if a straight line is drawn on the canvas I have to check if it intersects the polygon's any side or it is inside the polygon. If any of these is true (intersects or inside) I have to return true.

I am writing code on Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean line segment rather than infinite line.

You can check whether segment intersects any polygon edge (check them all) with intersection detection algorithm ([arbitrary found example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043805/test-if-two-lines-intersect-javascript-function))

In case of false result also check one segment end with [point in polygon test](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html)

If you expect that "inside" case is more frequent - do "point in polygon" first.

Perhaps similar functions already exist in your framework.

---

Also note that there are simpler methods for axis-aligned rectangle (box)

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the implicit equation of the line of support of your segment (as you say that "inside" is possible, your "line" must be a segment). It has the form

```
s(x, y) = a x + b y + c = 0
```

and `S` is positive on one side of the line and negative on the other side.

Now take every polygon side in turn and plug the coordinates of the two vertices. If the `S` changes sign between the vertices, the side intersects the line.

Now the trick is to use the parametric equation of the line *from one endpoint to the other* and find the intersection with the line in terms of the parameter `t` along the line. Note that the segment will correspond to the `t` interval `[0, 1]`.

After scanning the whole polygon, you will have a list of t values. If the list is empty, no intersection. If all values in the list are `<0` or `>1`, no intersection. Otherwise, there is an intersection (one subsegment or more).