# How do I fix this JS function so it doesn't return false positives when checking if two line segments intersect?

Tags: javascript, geometry, intersection, line-intersection

I'm working on a mapping project (with the Google Maps SDK). Before drawing a line segment on the map I check to see if it intersects with any existing lines.

I'm experiencing a situation where the code below is reporting the line segments are intersecting, but they're not. Although, they do share an endpoint.

Perhaps this `intersect()` function isn't meant to be used with Geo coordinates and I need a different function. I found this intersects() function here: [Test if two lines intersect - JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043805/test-if-two-lines-intersect-javascript-function)

In this project I have about 150 lines and about 10-15 of them are detected as intersecting, and they're not (although they share a common endpoint with the line that is reported as intersecting).

Below is a screenshot of how the lines are drawn on Google Maps for a better visual. The red line is the second one passed to the `intersects()` function and is detected as intersecting the first line. Interestingly, if I reverse the lines passed to `intersects()` it does not find them to be intersecting.

```js
let crosses = intersects(
        39.018223, -76.75899, 39.018387, -76.758773,
        39.018387, -76.758773, 39.019813, -76.757388,
);
      
console.log('Intersects:', crosses);

// returns true if the line from (a,b)->(c,d) intersects with (p,q)->(r,s)
function intersects(a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s) {
        var det, gamma, lambda;
        det = (c - a) * (s - q) - (r - p) * (d - b);
        if (det === 0) {
                console.log('det is zero');
                return false;
        } else {
                lambda = ((s - q) * (r - a) + (p - r) * (s - b)) / det;
                gamma = ((b - d) * (r - a) + (c - a) * (s - b)) / det;
                return (0 < lambda && lambda < 1) && (0 < gamma && gamma < 1);
        }
};
```

[image: Two lines]

Comment: So maybe add a check to see if their endpoints matches?

Comment: It's not really an answer to my question, so I'll add it as a comment. I ended up checking the line in the opposite order. If the first order fails (such as intersects(a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s)), I try in the opposite order (such as intersects(p,q,r,s, a,b,c,d)). that seems to be working well - no false positives yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for numerical precision. As mentioned in a comment of the post, you could test for endpoints but it would add a lot more computation. Another method is to account for precision in the final test by adding an epsilon to the comparison:

```
let epsilon = 1e-6;
return (epsilon < lambda && lambda < 1-epsilon) &&
       (epsilon <  gamma && gamma  < 1-epsilon);
```