# Using object.Equals to compare two float[] array-elements are equal

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have two `float[]` objects.  Without writing a for-loop, I want to compare my two 1D arrays to see if they are equal numerically or not.

When I run the following code (as all elements are equal), it doesn't go through the if-statement and show the message.

How should I apply the **Equals** command to work properly?
Is there any compare-command I could use?

```
 Random r1 = new Random(1);
   int rndNumber= r1.Next(10);
   float[] m = Enumerable.Repeat((float)rndNumber, 180).ToArray();
   float[] m2 = Enumerable.Repeat((float)rndNumber, 180).ToArray();
   if (m.Equals(m2))
    {
    MessageBox.Show("we are equal");
   }
```

Comment: Side note: comparing floats with ==/Equals is dangerous due to nature of float computations... make sure you really need ==, not something else.

Comment: @ Alexie: what's the dangerous side? Could you give me an example please

Comment: Bing result for "comparing floats..." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Equal` method for `Array` isn't overridden from the default `object` implementation that just compares the references of the objects (which aren't equal).

You want to compare the values of each element in the sequence, and ensure it has the same content in the same order.  To do that, use `SequenceEqual` in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

```
if(m.SequenceEqual(m2)) {...}
```

Internally that method will iterate through each element of each sequence and call `Equals` on each element pair to verify that they are all the same.  While this is certainly *easier* (and arguably more readable) to use than a for loop, keep in mind that it will perform no better than using a `for` loop, it's just hiding the loop from you.