# Minimal double type number in C aften which comupter start thinking that its zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, double, console-application

Sorry for my english. Can you tell me the smallest double type number after which the computer considers that the double type number equals zero?

Comment: Zero is zero.  Other numbers are not zero, floating point or not.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @CarlNorum numbers such as `1e-10000`

Comment: @johnchen902 gave a right example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual zero is zero. The result can become zero in different ways. A double has an value range of +/-10^<sup>+/-308</sup> (roughly). A number smaller than the smallest number will be considered zero. Using `#include <limits>`, you can get `numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()`, which is the smallest value that can be represented in a `double`.

But you can get "the effect of zero" in other ways. Say you have a fairly large number, 10 million, and you add (or subtract - read add as add or subtract in the rest of this paragraph) a very small number, say 1/10 million, then the addition will have no effect, because it is outside the actual value bits of the mantissa of the floating point number - that is, 53 bits in the case of `double` - then the effect will be the same as adding zero. In other words, even if you have a number that is not zero, using it to add to another number is not always going to change the other number.

See [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) on Wikipedia (other floating point formats do exist, but they are unusual).

Comment: More precisely `numeric_limits<double>::min()`.

Comment: 1) `denorm_min` can be smaller than `min`,  2) rounding modes can cause arbitrarily small values to be rounded to denorm_min and not zero.

Comment: -1, until you change that `numeric_limits<double>::min()` to `numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()`. `numeric_limits<double>::min()` is the smallest normalized number that can be represented as a double. Values smaller than that are possible. It's `numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()` that is the smallest value that can be represented as a double.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
#include <limits>
std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min();
```

Doc for denormal (aka subnormal) numbers ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)).

If this number is divided by e.g. by 2 the result is 0.

To check this values on a specific platform the following code can be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    typedef double real;
    union dbl {
        real d;
        unsigned char c[sizeof(d)];

        dbl(const dbl &n = 0.0) : d(n.d) {}
        dbl(double n) : d(n) {}

        void pr(const char *txt = 0) const {
            if (txt) cout << txt << ": ";
            cout << d << ":";
            for (int i = sizeof(d) -1; i >= 0; --i)
                cout << std::hex << " " << (int)c[i];
            cout << endl;
        }
    };

    dbl n = 1.0;
    for (; n.d > 0.0; n.d /= 2.0)
        n.pr();
    n.pr("zero");
    n.d = std::numeric_limits<real>::min();
    n.pr("min");
    n.d = std::numeric_limits<real>::denorm_min();
    n.pr("denorm_min");
}
```

Output on 32 bit linux (intel cpu) ([doc about double format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)):

```
1: 3f f0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.5: 3f e0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.25: 3f d0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.125: 3f c0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.0625: 3f b0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
8.9003e-308: 0 30 0 0 0 0 0 0
4.45015e-308: 0 20 0 0 0 0 0 0
2.22507e-308: 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0
1.11254e-308: 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
5.56268e-309: 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
7.90505e-323: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10
3.95253e-323: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8
1.97626e-323: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
9.88131e-324: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
4.94066e-324: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
zero: 0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
min: 2.22507e-308: 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0
denorm_min: 4.94066e-324: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

If `real` is defined as `long double` the output is:

```
1: 0 0 3f ff 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.5: 0 0 3f fe 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.25: 0 0 3f fd 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.125: 0 0 3f fc 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.0625: 0 0 3f fb 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
5.83232e-4950: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10
2.91616e-4950: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8
1.45808e-4950: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
7.2904e-4951: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
3.6452e-4951: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
zero: 0: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
min: 3.3621e-4932: 0 0 0 1 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
denorm_min: 3.6452e-4951: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Or for `float`:

```
1: 3f 80 0 0
0.5: 3f 0 0 0
0.25: 3e 80 0 0
0.125: 3e 0 0 0
0.0625: 3d 80 0 0
...
2.24208e-44: 0 0 0 10
1.12104e-44: 0 0 0 8
5.60519e-45: 0 0 0 4
2.8026e-45: 0 0 0 2
1.4013e-45: 0 0 0 1
zero: 0: 0 0 0 0
min: 1.17549e-38: 0 80 0 0
denorm_min: 1.4013e-45: 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza: a double with fraction less then denorm_min considered as zero.

Comment: @TrueY and how do you get that number?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Which number? The smallest positive double can be get using `double d = std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min();`. I added some example to my answer. If You divided this number by e.g. 2, You would get zero.

Comment: @NDGO: see the extended answer.

Comment: Aside: If you use C I/O you can get a portable hexadecimal representation of a double precision number with the `"%a"` format. C++ does not offer that.

Comment: @DavidHammen: You are right, but the tag is C++, so I would like to use the C++ style. Otherwise I could use `float.h` and `DBL_MIN`. Anyway `DBL_MIN` seems to be equal to `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`, not `denorm_min()`.

Comment: I was writing about how you generated that hex output, not the values such as `DBL_MIN`. For example, `printf ("%a", double_val)`. As far as I can see, there isn't any C++ flag that let you generate that `"%a"` format. `hex` applies to integers only, even in C++11.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Maybe I'm wrong, but in C++ I like to use the C++-ish solutions. I prefer to use `cout <<` instead of `printf` in C++ code. BTW I do not really like the `cout <<` syntax and I prefer `printf`. But this is a C++ example. :)

Comment: C library functions are callable from C++. Arguably, the C I/O library *is* a part of C++, accessible via the C++ (not C) header `<cstdio>`.

Comment: @DavidHammen: You are absolutely right about that! As I said I just did not like to add C style code to a C++ example. Sorry for that!

Comment: Try adding `#include <fenv.h>` and then in main before the loop: `fesetround(FE_UPWARD);` (you may then want to compile with `-frounding-math` if you use gcc or `-O0` with llvm). Now enjoy the infinite loop ;-)

Comment: @MarcGlisse:Thx for the comment! Is it still an infinite loop if it is divided by for example 10?

Comment: How about trying it? (yes, the theoretical result is between 0 and denorm_min, and if the rounding is towards +infinity, that means denorm_min)

Answer (score 1):

In *the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754*

The smallest positive normal value of `double` is `0x1.0p-1022` `2.2250738585072014E-308`.

The smallest positive denormal value of `double` is `0x0.0000000000001P-1022` `4.9e-324`.

The smallest positive normal value of `float` is `0x1.0p-126f` `1.17549435E-38f`.

The smallest positive denormal value of `float` is `0x0.000002P-126f` `1.4e-45f`.

Positive numbers smaller than above may result in `0`, depending on the rounding-mode as Marc Glisse commented.

Comment: These values you state are platform dependent.  You'd be better off taking them from the [<limits>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/) library.

Comment: Depends on the rounding mode, arbitrarily small numbers may be rounded to non-zero if the rounding direction is "up" or "away from zero".

Answer (score -1):

When you compare a double value that has been calculated, you should never check equality.  You should check to see if is within a range.  Not doing so would lead to the strong possibility that what you think is true is not so.

This is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison).

Comment: your advice is rather interesting, I will read "this question"