# c++ switch [Error] 'x' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++

im trying to execute this script its for my university

```
int main()
{
int x;
double y;

Provo:
cout<<"Vlera e X: ";
cin>>x;
switch(x)
{
    case ((x)<(0.9)):
        y=x*x;
        break;
    case (x==0.9):
        y=2*x;
        break;
    case 'x>0.9':
        y=x-3;
        break;
}   
cout<<"\n\n";
return 0;
}
```

this is teh code and the error is:

```
17  10  ....\Untitled1.cpp  [Error] 'x' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

someone help please?

Comment: Switch cases need compile-time constants. You can't base them off of user input. What you really need from the start is if-else. Switches only do equality.

Comment: Use if else instead. Also, x is an int and will never equal 0.9.

Comment: Also, x is an int so it will never be == 0.9; it could be bigger or smaller only

Comment: Yes, in the C-based languages you cannot have case statements with `> <` tests -- they must be exactly equal.  I'm vaguely recalling that Modula or Pascal supports `> <` tests.

Comment: Your last (3rd) case statement has single quotes... for no good reason. And you have a label, `Provo` that suggests you've thought about [goto](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png).   [What is this?](http://files.sharenator.com/picard-s300x266-70882.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood [how to use the `switch` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch). `switch` is used to branch your code based on the condition, in your case `x`, taking different integral values. It is not suitable for use with double values like you do.

A correct switch expression would look like:

```
switch(x)
{
case 1:
    y=x*x;
    break;
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
    y=2*x;
    break;
case 5:
    y=x-3;
    break;
}
```

To accomplish what you want, use `if` `else` instead, for example:

```
if (x < 0.9) {
    y=x*x;
else if(x == 0.9) {
    y=2*x;
} else {
    y=x-3;
}
```

However, [comparing floating point values for equality is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison). It is usually better to do something like:

```
double epsilon = <some small value>;
if (x < 0.9-epsilon) {
    y=x*x;
else if(x > 0.9+epsilon) {
    y=x-3;
} else {
    y=2*x;
}
```

Comment: FYI, logical expressions are valid syntax for `case`.  The line `case 'x>0.9'` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I guess you are right, but I think not with the semantic the OP expects, right?