# Comparing double error C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, double

recently I bump into a problem while comparing a double in an if statement. I was trying to cout the number of whole numbers in a double. Being a beginner, I am not sure what gone wrong in my code.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int x=0;//convert double to int
long double Out;//Result
long double In=10;//Input double

//Loop Begin
while(In>0){
x=In;//convert double to int
Out= (x/In);//Out(test if whole number, will return 1)

//test for 1
////////////////
if(Out == 1 ){
    cout<<"[Whole Number] ";
}
////////////////
//test end

cout<<"In :"<<In<<", ";
cout<<"X :"<<x<<", ";
cout<<"Out :"<<Out<<endl;
In-=0.1;//decrease to finish loop (eventually)
}
//Loop End

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

This program will test and output the whole numbers in the double (In). I realized that the accuracy of the double was affecting the if statement which is why I can't get the "[Whole Number]" result. Although I found out that if I used (0.9999) in "if(Out >= 0.9999)" the comparison would work. But I am not sure of a solution, please help! Much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I do floating point comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop never stops , its a infinite loop . You are not doing anything with the value of "In" in the while loop hence it will always be greater than 0 ,therefore a infinite loop .

Answer (score 0):

You should probably approach the problem more directly with `modf`:

```
double int_part, frac_part;

frac_part = std::modf(in, &int_part);

if (frac_part == 0) {
  // int_part contains integer value.
} else {
  // process the double non-integer floating point value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. If you subtract 0.1 from 10.0, then chances are that the result is *not* an integer due to rounding errors, and your code tells you exactly that. The code isn't wrong, your expectations are wrong.

```
if (Out >= 0.9999)
```

is obviously not a solution, because it will always be true if In >= 10000.0.

Answer (score 0):

Do to the way floating point numbers are converted to binary representation by the computer they are inherently inaccurate and thus make logical comparisons somewhat challenging (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). When performing such comparisons to floating point numbers you typically will do so utilizing an epsilon constant (http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) that represents the maximum acceptable error in the comparison. In your case you need to select a suitable value for epsilon (say .000001). Then change your comparison to:

```
if(abs(out - 1) < epsilon){ //Take the difference between out and 1
    cout<<"[Whole Number]"; //If it is "close enough" print to console
```

}

I am more of a Java guy but I believe you will need #include stdlib.h to utilize the abs() function.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

Try using the modulus operator: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Something like if(In % 1 == 0) should work.

Comment: My bad, not too familiar with c++