# Base-10 floating point in Swift

Tags: swift

I read about swift floating point types which are :

> The Swift standard library provides three signed floating-point number >types: Float for 32-bit floating-point numbers, Double for 64-bit floating >point numbers, and Float80 for extended-precision 80-bit floating-point >
>   numbers.

But I didn't see a "base 10" decimal type. and I think it is represented in base 2 because :

```
let g1 = (Double(0.1)+Double(0.2) );
println(g1==Double(0.3)) //false
```

*Question:*

How can I make this to evaluate to true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift has the same base-10 numerical type as ObjC has had for years: [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html).

One nice change in Swift is that you can, if you choose, [add operator overloads](https://gist.github.com/mattt/1ed12090d7c89f36fd28) to simplify its usage.

```
import Foundation

public func +(lhs: NSDecimalNumber, rhs: NSDecimalNumber) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    return lhs.decimalNumberByAdding(rhs)
}

let g1 = (NSDecimalNumber(double:0.1) + NSDecimalNumber(double:0.2) );
println(g1==NSDecimalNumber(double:0.3)) // true
```

If you want to have even more certainty of avoiding rounding errors (there's a possible rounding error when you take a value through the implicit double-convertion to get it to `NSDecimalNumber(double:)`), you can use the more explicit, integer-based interface that cannot suffer rounding:

```
let point1 = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 1, exponent: -1, isNegative: false);
let point2 = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 2, exponent: -1, isNegative: false);
```

You may be tempted to use `NSDecimalNumber(string:)`, and it's useful, but you have to be very careful about locales. You probably want to use `systemLocale()` (which is really a "fallback" locale with fixed settings) to avoid comma-vs-dot confusion:

```
let g2 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.1", locale:NSLocale.systemLocale())
```

But I'd avoid strings here and use the other techniques that are safer.

Comment: Can yoinplease supply 3 lines of working code for my example ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly? There's just no clean solution.

Others have written a `fuzzyEquals` method that compares only to the **n**th decimal place.
[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison).