# Swift: Using NSTimer to call an action

Tags: swift, nstimer

I'm trying to figure how to call an action when an `AVAudioPlayer` hits specific second by using `NSTimer`.

Code:

```
var audioFile = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FileName", ofType: "mp3")!))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("checkPlaybackTime:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func checkPlaybackTime(timer:NSTimer){
    let seconds : NSTimeInterval = audioFile.currentTime
    if (seconds == 20.0){
        btnPausePlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

The action that I wanted to call is that the btnPausePlay button text sets to "Play" which it never does as you see as I've called it in the if statement.

Edit: It now works. I changed from `if (seconds == 20.0` to `if (seconds >= 20.0)`

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Method is not called or what?

Comment: I've checked the code. `checkPlaybackTime:` method is called every second.

Comment: make sure your base class is NSObject, else the NSTimer selector might crash.

Comment: @DanielKrom snippet shows that `viewDidLoad` method is overriden. I think we can easily assume that `UIViewController` is parent class.

Comment: "doesn't work or do its job" is not an acceptable description of your problem on Stack Overflow (or anywhere, really).  As such, I've voted to close your question.  Please update your question with more details regarding exactly what is happening and how it differs from your expected outcome.  Is it failing to compile?  Is it crashing?  Is `checkPlaybackTime(timer:)` called at all?  Is your `if seconds == 20.0` comparison failing (if it's even hitting, it's almost certainly failing like 99.999% of the time)?  If your code launching missiles?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4915462/2792531

Comment: @TomaszSzulc yea, so it should be called from other class maybe

Comment: I've edited my question. Basically I wanted the btnPausePlay button to set the text to "Play" (which it doesn't) when the audio is done. 20 seconds hence being the length of the audio file. It doesn't crash or anything, it just doesn't call the action.

Comment: So did you read and understand my answer and the link that nhgrif provided?

Comment: Yep. I took your suggestion by changing it to ">= 20" and it's working perfectly. Plus, I understand now what you pointed out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer does not make explicit use of `NSTimer`, it does leverage the method `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` of the `AVPlayer` class to achieve the same purpose:

After initialising your player, do this:

```
let observerInterval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.5, 100) //this sets the interval at every half second
timeObserverToken = audioPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(observerInterval, queue: nil, usingBlock: self.getPlaybackTimer)
```

Function `getPlaybackTimer` looks like this:

```
func getPlaybackTimer(time: CMTime){
    let currentTime = audioPlayer.currentTime()
    /* *** */
}
```

Comment: While this is neat and could be part of a correct answer, I suspect that the actual problem in the question asked has nothing to do with the choice to use `NSTimer`, and this answer does nothing to solve the actual problem.

Comment: I'm using AVAudioPlayer because it has methods like "stop(), numberOfLoops, playing() etc which I'm currently using. Is there an alternative for the addPerodic method in AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: @Justin, no, sadly `AVAudioPlayer` is not a subclass of `AVPlayer`, so that method is not available. If you strictly need the methods/properties in AVAudioPlayer, you'll have to stick with that class. AVPlayer does have a method that should be interesting to you: `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes `. It would allow you to trigger an action after a determined period of time (like your 20 seconds), which is more efficient than running a timer every second until you reach your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

As nhgrif points out, your logic is flawed. You are comparing floating point values in a way that you should not. You need to take little variations into account, almost always when comparing floating point numbers.

In this case, however, this wouldn't suffice alone, as your comparison might take place every so little outside your checking interval. You are better of by using inequality here, i.e. >= 20.0. You might want to disable the timer then.