# Surprising difference for Floating-Point Arrithmetic for Double vs Float

Tags: swift, floating-point, precision

```
var num1 = 1.1
if num1 + 0.1 == 1.2 {print("true")} else {print("false")}
```

Result: `false`

```
var num1: Float = 1.1
if num1 + 0.1 == 1.2 {print("true")} else {print("false")}
```

Result: `true`

The former block of code has num1 which represents a double and the latter code block has num1 which represents a float.

My question: Why does the code with Float return true and the one with Double does not?

Comment: @Leo Dabus The one you suggested does not answer my question. I do know that it talks about the precision of floating-point number, but there is no part of the discussion that mentions why float returns true and double does not. So please consider again and remove the duplicate from my question.

Comment: Float is single-precision and double is double-precision.

Comment: @Leo Dabus I think this is a valid question, i’m curious about the discrepancy between `Float` and `Double` too. If anything it should be the other way around…

Comment: @LeoDabus that doesn’t explain why the less precise format succeeds in the comparison, while the more precise format fails

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: It's not that interesting. It just accidentally rounded the right way.

Comment: comparing floating point numbers with `==` is always a problem and should not be done at all. You are at the mercy of rounding errors. And as this example shows, it may well happen that it works for float but doesn't for double.

Comment: Add `print((num1 + 0.1).debugDescription, Double(1.2).debugDescription)` to the first case and `print((num1 + 0.1).debugDescription, Float(1.2).debugDescription)` to the second case. You'll see that none of the numbers is "correct".

Answer (score 3):

This *is* a duplicate and I will close it as such, but here is an example of why this works for `Float` but not for `Double`.

Instead of looking at `Double` and `Float`, let's look at two new types. `Eighths` and `Sixteenths`.  `Eighths` has 3 bits to represent fractional numbers, so you can represent `0`, `0.125`, `0.25`, `0.375`, `0.5`, `0.625`, `0.75`, and `0.875`.  `Sixteenths` has 4 bits to represent fractional numbers, so you can represent `0`, `0.0625`, `0.125`, `0.1875`, `0.25`, and so on.  In both number types, it will be necessary to approximate floating point values by choosing the closest value to the one you wish to represent.

So lets look at what `1.1 + 0.1` looks like in `Eighths` and `Sixteenths`.

**Eighths**

```
1.1 = 1.125
0.1 = 0.125
1.2 = 1.25

1.1 + 0.1 = 1.125 + 0.125 = 1.25
```

so `1.1 + 0.1 == 1.2` in `Eighths`

**Sixteenths**

```
1.1 = 1.125
0.1 = 0.125
1.2 = 1.1875

1.1 + 0.1 = 1.125 + 0.125 = 1.25
```

so `1.1 + 0.1 != 1.2` in `Sixteenths`.

The greater precision of `Sixteenths` makes it possible to more accurately represent `1.2` with a smaller value when represented in `Sixteenths`.

This is what is happening with `Float`s and `Double`s.  There are more bits available to represent the numbers, but they are still approximations.  When you do math with those approximations, the error combines in unexpected ways which is why it is ill advised to be using equals comparisons with floating point values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! May I know how to compare floating point numbers if I can't use the equals comparisons?

Comment: This is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4915891/1630618