# Test if a random point belongs to a circumference of a circle using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a random point on the circumference of a circle using Python.

I have a circle of centre (0, 0) and of radius 50. I did the following.

```
import numpy as np
angle = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand()
x = np.cos(angle) * 50
y = np.sin(angle) * 50
```

But when I test to see if the point is actually on the circle circumference, I did this

```
x ** 2 + y ** 2 == 50 ** 2
```

but I get

```
False
```

Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: If you want to learn how to estimate the needed epsilon then google "numerical stability floating point math". Alas, its Wikipedia article is terrible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of floating point imprecision. In general, it is a bad idea to compare two floats for equality, and you should instead test to see if they are within a certain amount of each other. For example,

```
epsilon = 0.000001
print abs(x ** 2 + y ** 2  - 50 ** 2) <= epsilson
```

See also: [How should I do floating point comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)

Answer (score 3):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact, so testing for equality will not always work as would be expected with infinite precision.