# php fmod returning unusable result

Tags: php, modulo, fmod

```
fmod(floatval("314.6"), floatval("1.3"))
=> 1.1990408665952E-14
```

I understand more or less the underlying problem of representing the numbers in binary form and something with IEEE-754. But: How would I get a result that is usable in pratice?

**Example what I want to achieve:** A merchant can define the price P of his product, but the price has to be a multiple of x:

```
if (fmod(P, x) != 0) { echo "price must be a multiple of " . x; }
```

It would be so simple, but the approach fails whenever I get something like 1234E-18 as return value of `fmod()`.
What to do in real life to check the price interval easily without using custom code?

This or similar questions have been around, but all I can find are explanations why `fmod()` behaves like it does. Never an answer how to solve this real-life problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `314.6` is exactly `1.3 * 242` so floating point remainder is zero but you get `0.00000000000001199041` due to the IEEE 754 inaccuracies you're well aware of.

But don't forget one of the rules of floating point maths: you can't [compare floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison) for equality carelessly. If your arguments have one decimal position you don't need 14-position accuracy in your results. You have prices: how many decimals make sense in your currency? If you were using e.g. euros you're unlikely to use more than two (cents) and `1.1990408665952E-14` is zero to all effects:

```
var_dump(round(1.1990408665952E-14, 2));
```

> double(0)

Some people recommend doing all price maths using integers (e.g. cents instead of euros) to avoid rounding errors but most real life issues come from very specific errors:

- Displaying raw floats to user (rather than rounding and formatting them).
- Doing raw comparisons (`if ($foo == $bar)`).

… and integers don't prevent all rounding errors anyway (e.g. tax calculations on individual items not matching calculations on invoice totals).

Comment: i knew it's an easy question...thanks for this elaborate answer!