# concatenating two columns and get the new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have 2 col as

```
  Latitude       Longitude    
  35.827085869   -95.67496156
```

Both are in float and I want it to convert into

```
 Latitude       Longitude       final
 35.827085869   -95.67496156    [35.827085869,-95.67496156]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want a string or a list? And just curious, why would you want that?

Comment: `df['final']=df.values.tolist()
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the two columns to a list of lists, then assign it to a new column.

```
# Pandas < 0.24
# df['final'] = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values.tolist()
# Pandas >= 0.24
df['final'] = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].to_numpy().tolist()
df

    Latitude  Longitude                         final
0  35.827086 -95.674962  [35.827085869, -95.67496156]
```

Note that they *have* to be lists, you cannot assign them back as a single column if you're assigning a NumPy array.

---

Another choice is to use `agg` for reductions:

```
df['final'] = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].agg(list, axis=1)
df

    Latitude  Longitude                         final
0  35.827086 -95.674962  [35.827085869, -95.67496156]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use it as a common key to join into a data-frame but it's throwing TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' .Any ideas

Comment: @No_body In general, you use tuples, not lists when merging pairs: `df['final'] = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].agg(tuple, axis=1)`. But this is a bad idea. Bad, bad idea. You don't want to do this. You never want to do this. For the same reason that [people don't use `==` to compare floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison) (because of floating point inaccuracies). You asked an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/494004). Because you did not tell us what you needed it for, none of our solutions were useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

One more using `zip`

```
df['final']=list(zip(df.Latitude,df.Longitude))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `apply`:

```
df['final'] = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].apply(list, axis=1)

   Latitude              ...                                      final
0  35.827086              ...               [35.827085869, -95.67496156]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine them by typecasting each column as `str` then adding its values as strings together with the brackets you prefer, then finally placing them as values for the column `final`.

```
df['final'] = '[' + df['Latitude'].astype(str) + ', ' + df['Longitude'].astype(str) + ']'
```