# Binary of a float number in an if conditional

Tags: c, if-statement

Here's a code that i want to discuss

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a=0.1;
    if(a==0.1)
        printf("Stack");
    else
        printf("OverFlow");
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
OverFlow
```

Can i have an explanation of this output ? 
in my perspective i think that my machine couldn't find the binary representation of `0.1` (because the binary of `0.1`is an infinite number), is my intuition correct?

Comment: You're comparing a `float` `0.1` to a `double` `0.1`.  Since `0.1` cannot be exactly represented as a floating point number, the `double` version is more accurate and hence not equal to the `float` version.

Comment: `if(a == (float)0.1)` outputs `Stack`

Comment: Read up on floating point math.  In general, it is not possible to directly compare for equality on a floating point number and an epsilon value (+/- value) is generally applied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison

Comment: The intuition was right, `1/10` recurs, as does `1/7` in decimal, but the approximation would have been consistent if you hadn't used different (`float` and `double`) representations of `0.1` which is of type `double`.

Comment: `float a=0.1;` -> `double a=0.1;` and then try again

Comment: For more insight `printf("%.20f %.20f\n", 0.1, 0.1f);`