# error: The input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Checking for number 3 in Text

error:

**The input string was not in the correct format**

```
public Text Timer;
   
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Convert.ToDouble(Timer.text) == 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("w");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was the text box empty?

Comment: you are better off with Double.TryParse it will tell you if the field is not correct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Print your `Timer.text` as `Debug.Log("'" + Timer.text + "'");`. Note single quote in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we don't know which string content your `Time.text` has but you should rather use either [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) or since everything in the Unity API uses `float` anyway maybe rather [`float.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse). Alternatively you can also cast it to `(float)` since you are wanting to compare it basically to an `int` value anyway the precision doesn't really matter.

Because a second point is: You should **never** directly compare floating point type numbers via `==` (See [How should I do floating point comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)). It is possible that a `float` (or double) value logically should have the value `3` like e.g. `(3f + 3f + 3f) / 3f` but due to the floating point imprecision results in a value like `2.9999999999` or `3.000000001` in which case a comparing to `3` might fail unexpectedly.

Rather use the Unity built-in [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) which basically equals using

```
if(Math.Abs(a-b) <= epsilon)
```

where [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html)

> The smallest value that a float can have different from zero.

So I would recommend to rather do something like

```
if (double.TryParse(Timer.text, out var time) && Mathf.Approximately((float)time, 3))
{
    Debug.Log("w");
}
```

---

Note however that if this is a timer that is continuously increased you might **never exactly** hit the value `3` so you might want to either use a certain threshold range around it like

```
if (double.TryParse(Timer.text, out var time) && time - 3 >= someThreshold)
{
    Debug.Log("w");
}
```

or simply use e.g.

```
if (double.TryParse(Timer.text, out var time) && time >= 3)
{
    Debug.Log("w");
}
```

if you only want any value bigger or equal to `3`.