# How to decrement a float variable until it's exactly zero

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I am making keyboard controls for a camera, and I am experiencing issues regarding the innacuracy of floats. I have the variables "float Xvelocity" and "float Zvelocity", I increment these velocities by adding or subtracting the acceleration speed every time the respective direction keys are being held (A, D, W or S).
However, everything I try to make the float go towards zero simply work in very strange ways. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
if (keys[GLFW_KEY_A] & xVelocity >-speed)
    xVelocity -= acceleration / deltaTime;
if (keys[GLFW_KEY_D] & xVelocity < speed)
    xVelocity += acceleration / deltaTime;
if (keys[GLFW_KEY_W] & zVelocity >-speed)
    zVelocity -= acceleration / deltaTime;
if (keys[GLFW_KEY_S] & zVelocity < speed)
    zVelocity += acceleration / deltaTime;

if (!keys[GLFW_KEY_A] & xVelocity<0.f) {
    xVelocity+=deceleration / deltaTime;
}
if (!keys[GLFW_KEY_D] & xVelocity>0.f) {
    xVelocity-=deceleration / deltaTime;
}
if (!keys[GLFW_KEY_W] & zVelocity<0.f) {
    zVelocity+=deceleration / deltaTime;
}
if (!keys[GLFW_KEY_S] & zVelocity>0.f) {
    zVelocity-=deceleration / deltaTime;
}

origin -= right * xVelocity;
origin -= vec3(front.x, 0.f, front.z) * zVelocity;
```

This doesn't make my camera completely stop moving! It does decelerate, but it rarely becomes exactly zero, thus it keeps slowly moving after releasing the key, either towards the direction it was going before or away from it. Can someone explain why doesn't this deceleration work as I intended, (probably because of float inaccuracy, but maybe it's another reason) and how may I proceed to fix it?

Comment: Please define _best_ by which means. _"but it rarely becomes exactly zero"_ Does this answer your question: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)? You do `float`comparisons wrong. Use [`std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ reformulated, I just want to decrement until it becomes zero, but it's not as easy with floats as with Integer values

Comment: Use an *epsilon* to compare against zero. Like `abs(value_that_should_be_zero - epsilon) == 0.0` Also see [How should I do floating point comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)

Comment: `if (std::fabs(velocity) < tol) velocity = 0.0f;` so check if it's below some numerical tolerance than just assign to `0.0f` instead of doing arithmetic to get it there

Comment: I will check out std::epsilon, thanks for the recommendation guys.

Comment: BTW: If you really have an acceleration as input and you want to obtain the velocity you'd rather have to increment it like ```xVelocity -= acceleration * deltaTime;```. Your formulation doesn't make sense physically (sorry to put it so bluntly). But again, I don't know how you have defined acceleration and if it is really representative of a physical acceleration.

Comment: Don't use `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon`. That's a detail for expert use. In your case, just decide: how close to zero do you want velocity to get before you treat it as zero? And then just do it. See the comment by @CoryKramer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Please do not jump to conclusions about floating-point questions and promiscuously close them as duplicates of that question. This was a math problem, not a floating-point problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a floating-point accuracy issue unless your `acceleration`, `deltaTime`, and `velocity` are calibrated so that, mathematically, `velocity` reaches zero exactly after an integer number of steps. More likely, the problem is simply that your `velocity` is not an exact multiple of `acceleration/deltaTime`, even allowing for floating-point issues. For example, suppose `velocity` is 3.7 and `acceleration/deltaTime` is .2. Then `velocity` will step through 3.5, 3.3, 3.1,… .5, .3, .1, and −.1.

So `velocity` never becomes zero because it crosses right through it. When `velocity` is at .1 units, you can never decelerate by .2 units; an object stops when its velocity reaches zero.

A solution is to detect this and clamp the result to zero:

```
if (!keys[GLFW_KEY_A] & xVelocity<0.f)
{
    xVelocity = xVelocity >= - deceleration / deltaTime ? 0 : xVelocity + deceleration / deltaTime;
}
```