# How to compare numbers correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, compare, legend

I want to compare 2 values based on which I get the color for my legend. But unfortunately I cannot use ceil, floor or round the values as it will effect my result.

I have following color table with first value as point and rest 3 values are r g b values.

Basically I get point from backend which ca be 0.4607441262895224, 0.5500956769649571 and so on. I need to compare the point with first value in color table and give corresponding color. But I am facing issue in comparing , as currently I have given to Fixed(2) but it is not recommended.

```
"colors": [
[ 0.00, 255, 13, 186 ],
[ 0.25, 254, 4, 135 ],
[ 0.50, 73, 255, 35 ],
[ 0.75, 185, 116, 255 ],
[ 1.00, 32, 50, 255 ]
]

// main logic
const test = arraySet.find((ele) => {
  // point is dynamic
  const point = 0.388920938
  // I cannot use toFixed(2) here, which need to be changed
  // ele[0] is the first value in array 0.00, 0.25, 0.50 and so on
  return point.toFixed(2) == ele[0].toFixed(2);}
);
```

Comment: why are you using toFixed() if you just want to compare them ?

Comment: @Saren Yes, thats wrong. I cannot use toFixed() and dont know how can I compare it

Comment: if point is a number and ele is a number you can just do this ```point === ele```

Comment: point is something like 0.4607441262895224 or 0.5500956769649571 and so on dynamic values and ele can be 0.00 or 0.25 or 0.50 and so on

Comment: You can use @kikon's answer with a threshold of something like `0.125` so that every dynamic point will be matched to one of the fixed points assuming that your dynamic points are between 0 and 1

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want something on the lines of

```js
Math.abs(point-ele[0]) < 0.01
```

replace `0.01` with a threshold relevant to your data, e.g., `1e-6` for 10^(-6)

Comment: Yes, even I assume that I need some thresold but may I know what can I replace with 0.01, as I am not familiar with thresold.

Comment: Well,it depends on your values, what range of values they can take and when do you consider them to be sufficiently close to be equal

Comment: You didn't use the standard `point===ele` so I assume you wanted to consider numbers equal even if they are not perfectly equal, but close within a certain range.

Comment: How about using Math.abs(point - ele) < Number.EPSILON ?

Comment: That's not a good idea in general, for a better solution see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison). But I suspect your differences are not only related to floating point precision. Do you but any chance want to find the `ele` in the array that is closest to `point`?

Comment: Not sure though as I am new to the project and team, need to check with other team members. Hopefully I will have answer for your question soon.

Answer (score 0):

ToFixed will also be rounded

```
const toFixed=(num)=>Number(num.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));
```

Comment: True, but rounding can be misleading; consider `0.135.toFixed(2)` and `0.134999.toFixed(2)`

Comment: I didn't write a function, But I always do *100/100

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
return point.toString().substr(0, ele.toString().length) == ele;
```