# Array method is not showing up (C#)

Tags: c#

I need help! the output should be prompted to enter student name and their GPA in CreateStudentList() method like how I typed it out.
But the output only shows this
*Student List1 GPAs:
Student List2 GPAs:*

What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I called the createstudentlist() method?

```
class Student
{
    public string strName;
    public float fltGPA;

    public Student(string n, float gpa)
    {
        strName = n;
        fltGPA = gpa;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void DisplayStudentList(List<Student> slist)
    {
        foreach(Student s in slist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", s.fltGPA);
        }
    }
    static List<Student> CreateStudentList()
    {
        List<Student> studentlist = new List<Student>();
        Student objStudent;

        string r = "";
        while (r == "Y")
        {
            Console.Write("Enter name:");
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter GPA:");
            float g = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            objStudent = new Student(n, g);
            studentlist.Add(objStudent);

            Console.Write("Do you want to continue? (Y/N): ");
            r = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return studentlist;
        
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> studentList1 =  CreateStudentList();
        List<Student> studentList2 = CreateStudentList();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Student List1 GPAs:");
        DisplayStudentList(studentList1);
        Console.WriteLine("Student List2 GPAs:");
        DisplayStudentList(studentList2);

        foreach (Student gpa1 in studentList1)
        {
            foreach (Student gpa2 in studentList2)
            {
                if (gpa1.fltGPA == gpa2.fltGPA)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Students with same GPA: \n {0} \n {1}",
                        gpa1.strName, gpa2.strName);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `string r = "";
        while (r == "Y")` its never `Y` at first, so it doesnt enter into the loop. Have you set breakpoints and stepped through your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
string r = "";
while (r == "Y") 
{ ...
```

The while loop will never be entered. Either set `r = "Y"` or use a [do/while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement) loop.

Another thing to consider:

```
if (gpa1.fltGPA == gpa2.fltGPA)
```

compares floats by equality. You should use a [comparison with epsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)

Comment: Ahhh okay i get it now! so sorry i just started learning arrays for C# and was confused with how it works.. thank you so much!