# How to pass a template struct as parameter C++

Tags: c++, templates, struct, parameters

I got this template:

```
template <typename T>
struct List {
    struct node {
        T key;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
    };
    node* first = nullptr;
    node* last = nullptr;
    // functions
};
```

I need to create a function OUTSIDE of the struct that takes a List as a parameter.
I tried something but doesnt work

```
void palindrome(List<typename T> L)
```

Comment: Proper way would be implement for list: `begin`, `end`,  `rbegin`, `rend` and so on, then use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71437826/1387438 but this might be to hard for you for now.

Comment: Not only classes but also functions can be templates, basically exactly for your scenario: `template<typename T> void palindrome(List<T> t) {}`.

Comment: Alternatively, if the function caters just to one specific list element type, a specific List instantiation is basically an ordinary type, e.g. `void f(List<char> cl) {}`. (That function is not a template. It does not depend on any type that can vary at compile time.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `List` is a class template (not template class / struct, it is not a class). You cannot pass a template to a function. You can only pass objects of some type to a function. `List` is not a type. `List<double>` for example is a type. So you could do for example:

```
void palindrome(List<double> L);
```

However, I suppose you want to pass any instantation of `List` to the function, eg a `List<double>` or a `List<int>` etc. Then you can make the function itself a function template:

```
template <typename T>
template void palindrome(List<T> l);
```

Note that this is not a function that accepts any instanatiation of `List`. It is just a template, and calling it with a `List<int>` or a `List<double>` will instantiate two distinct functions.

Sometimes it is simpler to be more generic, and you can do as well

```
template <typename L>
template void palindrome(L l);
```

Comment: You should also fix problem with list copy.

Answer (score 1):

In your function the typename T is unbound. The compiler has no idea what to do with that. You need to create a template function like this:

```
template<typename T> void palindrome(List<T> t) {}
```

The compiler will then deduce the typename T when you use the function.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a **class template** which is diferent from a ***class type***. A *class type* would be `List<int>` or a `List<double>` etc.

You can make `palindrome` a **function template** that has a **parameter** of type `List<T>` for some type `T`, as shown below.

```
//a function template that has parameter of type List<T> 
template<typename T>
void palindrome(List<T> L)
{
    std::cout<<"palindrome called"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    List<int> l1;
    //call 
    palindrome(l1);//T will be deduced to int 
    
    List<double> l2;
    //call 
    palindrome(l2); //T will be deduced to double
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gOO6_RAOS)