# Testing if two f64 series are equal

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

I am trying to write tests for various algorithms in my crate. However, I have come across a bit of a hurdle regarding how f64 values behave. They both return the same value, but I'm not too sure of the precision of the calculated series, because the assertion fails.

```rust
fn floating_point() {
    let s1 = Series::new("a", vec![1.0, 5.0, 7.7]);
    let s2 = Series::new("a", vec![4.566667]);

    let avg = s1.mean_as_series();
    println!("{}", avg);
    println!("{}", s2);
    assert!(s2.series_equal(&avg))
}
```

```bash
shape: (1,)
Series: 'a' [f64]
[
        4.566667
]
shape: (1,)
Series: 'a' [f64]
[
        4.566667
]
```

What would be the recommended way to determine if 2 series like this are equivalent?
I have looked into rounding the series, but I am looking for alternatives to that. The behaviour seems to be inconsistent with 5 decimal points on different series. some fail, some pass.

Also, what would be the way to do this with a Dataframe without extracting the series?

Comment: The best way to test float equality is to check that the (magnitude of the) difference between the two floats is sufficiently close to 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison