# infinite while loop although I put break statement

Tags: python, floating-point, infinite-loop

this code is supposed to take slope (m) and y-intercept (b) of two lines and checks if these two line hit each other or not.
the problem is my while loop is infinite although I have condition and break statement

```
print("enter the first m: ")
m = input()  # m = slope

print("enter the first b: ")
b = input()  # b = y-intercept

print("enter the second m: ")
m1 = input()

print("enter the second b: ")
b1 = input()

sub_m = int(m) - int(m1) #sub = subtract
sub_b = int(b) - int(b1)

if (sub_m == 0):
    print("parallel")

x = float(-sub_b / sub_m)
r = round(x, 1)

i = 0.0
while i != r:

    print(r, i)
    if (i == r):
        print("\nhit piont: ", i)
        break

    if (sub_m > 0 and sub_b > 0):
        i -= 0.1
    elif (sub_m < 0 and sub_b < 0):
        i -= 0.1
    else:
        i += 0.1
```

Comment: Your `break` statement cannot be reached because if the `if`s condition would be fulfilled, the loop would already finished, as the `while`'s condition is opposite.
As for why it is an infinite loop, probably it's because you're comparing floating point numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison

Comment: @JohnKugelman
both i and r are float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this in my debugger showed that you're getting floating point representation errors. This means that although technically you should be getting numbers perfectly rounded to 1 decimal given that you're applying increments of 0.1, in reality this isn't the case:

[image]

As you can see, `r = -2.0` and `i = -2.00...4`, thus at no point is `r == i`.

You can fix this by adding another round statement at the end:

```py
print("enter the first m: ")
m = input()  # m = slope

print("enter the first b: ")
b = input()  # b = y-intercept

print("enter the second m: ")
m1 = input()

print("enter the second b: ")
b1 = input()

sub_m = int(m) - int(m1) #sub = subtract
sub_b = int(b) - int(b1)

if (sub_m == 0):
    print("parallel")

x = float(-sub_b / sub_m)
r = round(x, 1)

i = 0.0
while i != r:

    print(r, i)

    if (sub_m > 0 and sub_b > 0):
        i -= 0.1
    elif (sub_m < 0 and sub_b < 0):
        i -= 0.1
    else:
        i += 0.1
    i = round(i, 1)  # <- this

print(f"Hit pt: {i}")
```

HOWEVER: This is still error prone, and I recommend finding a way to avoid `if i==r` altogether in the code. If `i` is lower than `r`, exit the loop when it finally becomes bigger, and viceversa. Its best practice to avoid using the `==` condition when comparing floats, and to find a way to use `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: this helped but it doesn't print hit point
@KikeLaguilhoat

Comment: @Mustang That's because it was leaving the while loop before getting to the if statement. I edited the code in my answer: Print the hit point after the loop has exited.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here seems to be adamant on using some fancy tricks to make floating comparison works. Why not just multiply it all by 10 and get rid of floats altogether? :-)

I don't know if it is the fastest solution but it should have less corner cases.

```py
i = 0
while True: # <- condition removed to allow the "hit point" if to work

    print(r, i / 10)
    if (i == r * 10):
        print("\nhit piont: ", i / 10)
        break

    if (sub_m > 0 and sub_b > 0):
        i -= 1
    elif (sub_m < 0 and sub_b < 0):
        i -= 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: **NO** the `i` must be float because in most of the cases hit point is not an integer

Comment: @Mustang In this code `i` is not the value of the hit point. `i` is hit point * 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of granularity and floating-point precision. You're incrementing i in steps of 0.1 and then checking, at each step, if `i == r`. But what if r is not an integer multiple of 0.1? Then i will never exactly equal r, and your `break` will never be triggered.

By the way, your `while` condition and your `if` condition are mutually exclusive; if i and r are equal, you never enter the loop, and consequently won't have to/be able to `break` out of it. What you want is probably a genuine infinite loop with `while True`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your while loop breaking condition contradicts your `if() break` condition. so it will never get to match the `if` condition. So it will never `print hit point`, because it will break the while loop when `l==r`, either it will never be `l==r` because of precision and loop infinite, so in both situations `if` condition never match. And comparing a floating value to `break` a loop is not ideal.