# How to generalize a comparison in Java code

Tags: java, interface, dry

Say I have a `Filter` interface

```java
public interface Filter {
   public boolean satisfies(Earthquake earthquake)
}
```

Which can have different implementations (one such below)

```java
public final class MagnitudeFilter implements Filter {

    private final double minimumMagnitude;
    private final double maximumMagnitude;
    private final ComparisonStrategy strategy;

    public MagnitudeFilter(double minimumMagnitude, double maximumMagnitude, ComparisonStrategy strategy) {
        this.minimumMagnitude = minimumMagnitude;
        this.maximumMagnitude = maximumMagnitude;
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean satisfies(Earthquake earthquake) {
        return switch (strategy) {
            case EXCLUSIVE -> earthquake.magnitude() > minimumMagnitude &&
                earthquake.magnitude() < maximumMagnitude;
            case INCLUSIVE -> earthquake.magnitude() >= minimumMagnitude &&
                earthquake.magnitude() <= maximumMagnitude;
        };
    }
}
```

In some cases I would like to perform an `inclusive` comparison and other times I would like to perform an `exclusive` comparison, however in the above form, I will need to repeat the `switch` expression for every single implementation.

Is there an alternative way that I can generalize this pattern for all implementations so as not to have to repeat the code in the switch statement?

Tried to user another interface but ended up in a loop of repeating code again.

Comment: Do you mean the other filters are all just testing if a particular property of an earthquake is within some range?

Comment: That is **not** how you want to [compare floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915891/2970947).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Comparing for greater/smaller is not really a problem unless you're working right at the edge of the float/double precision limit."

I'm not really working at the edge of the preicision limit here so I think double comparisons are fine in this scenario..?

Comment: @Sweeper yes that's right

Comment: @Ryan Your two filters are not comparing for greater/smaller, they only differ by comparing for exact equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `Filter` is basically identical to `java.util.function.Predicate`, so we can just use that.  You also don't need a subclass of `Filter`; just use lambdas.

In your example, the inclusive/exclusive choice travels with the filter, so all you have to do is define two factories:

```
Predicate<Earthquake> rangeInclusive(double min, double max) { 
    return e -> e.magnitude() > min && e.magnitude() <= max;
}

Predicate<Earthquake> rangeExclusive(double min, double max) { 
    return e -> e.magnitude() > min && e.magnitude() < max;
}
```

If you want to use data, rather than the method name, to select inclusive/exclusive, you can do that with the switch in just one place:

```
Predicate<Earthquake> range(double min, double max, ComparisonStrategy strat) { 
    return switch (strat) { 
        case INCLUSIVE -> e -> e.magnitude() > min && e.magnitude() <= max;
        case EXCLUSIVE -> e -> e.magnitude() > min && e.magnitude() < max;
}
```

Comment: Brian this is great thank you! And an honour to hear from you, actually reading your book!

Comment: I would argue that naming things may still be helpful in reading the code later. Perhaps, defining `interface Filter extends Predicate<Earthquake>` is the best of both worlds.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov As always, it depends.  Sometimes domain-specific names are extremely helpful; sometimes they are just clutter.  It is rare that you will know which when starting out, so don't spend a lot of time on that up front; wait until you know the shape of your solution.  And in general, inventing domain-specific names for common concepts like Predicate or List is usually more in the latter category; generally best to save the domain-specific names for your actual domain concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, that the general part of your code is whether the comparison is `INCLUSIVE` or `EXCLUSIVE`, while the wrapper `Filter` is mostly for the property extraction.

If I'm correct, then what about doing this:

```
public enum ComparisonStrategy {
  INCLUSIVE() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(double value, double min, double max) {
      return value >= min && value <= max;
    }
  },
  EXCLUSIVE() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(double value, double min, double max) {
      return value > min && value < max;
    }
  };

  public abstract boolean test(double value, double rangeStart, double rangeEnd);
}
```

So your filter becomes:

```
public final class MagnitudeFilter implements Filter {

  private final double minimumMagnitude;
  private final double maximumMagnitude;
  private final ComparisonStrategy strategy;

  public MagnitudeFilter(
      double minimumMagnitude, double maximumMagnitude,
      DoubleComparisonStrategy strategy) {
    this.minimumMagnitude = minimumMagnitude;
    this.maximumMagnitude = maximumMagnitude;
    this.strategy = strategy;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean satisfies(Earthquake earthquake) {
    return strategy.test(
      earthquake.magnitude(), minimumMagnitude, maximumMagnitude
    );
  }
}
```

Obvious downside of this approach is if your `ComparisonStrategy` is used to test for more than just `double` values (i.e. `long`s and `int`s too) - then you either will need to extract separate `DoubleComparisonStrategy`, `LongComparisonStrategy` enum classes, or make many methods like `boolean testDouble(double, double, double)`, `boolean testLong(long, long long)`, etc. in the "main" `ComparisonStrategy` class. It may not even be possible to define a proper comparison for all possible properties you would want to compare - i.e. it's going to be a lot harder to include a `Comparator<T>` into this mix when going with `enum` approach.

UPD: combining with the approach from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76431809/7470253), this makes:

```
Predicate<Earthquake> magnitudeInclusive(double min, double max) {
  return e -> ComparisonStrategy.INCLUSIVE.test(e.magnitude(), min, max);
}

Predicate<Earthquake magnitudeExclusive(double min, double max) {
  return e -> ComparisonStrategy.EXCLUSIVE.test(e.magnitude(), min, max);
}
```

Also, this will look the same if you still want to use `Filter` interface, because that is also a valid lambda target:

```
Filter magnitudeInclusive(double min, double max) {
  return e -> ComparisonStrategy.INCLUSIVE.test(e.magnidute(), min, max);
}
```