# Laravel PHP Variables Appear To Be Equal On Echo But Not in Comparison Statement

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I am stuck on something that should be very easy, I'm hoping I'm making a simple syntax or type error that I just can't see, so I need some help.

I'm doing form validation in Laravel to make sure that if someone sends me JSON from the client with the price of an item as `0` that it won't then charge the customer `0` dollars but will instead return an error using Laravel's `abort()`. My problem is even when the client-side `totalCost` and the `calculatedTotalCost` seem to be correct and identical when echoing them out, I still get the `abort()`.

Part of my code is below:

```
$totalCost= str_replace("$","",$totalCost);
$totalCost = (float)$totalCost;
if($calculatedTotalCost != $totalCost){
            abort(500, 'Your Order Cost Is Incorrect!'.$calculatedTotalCost." ".$totalCost);
            return;
           }
```

The thing is on the abort my response is:

```
Your Order Cost Is Incorrect!46.45 46.45
```

There it is, both `46.45` and I did the type conversion to a float so I don't understand why it throws the abort.

Comment: What  exactly is the value of `$totalCost` before the string replace?

Comment: Try `var_dump()` both variables and compare type. Obviously they are not the same values.

Comment: Try to replace `(float)` explicit cast by function `$totalCost = floatval($myString);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something about your floats make them slightly different at low decimal digits.  Try replacing

```
if($calculatedTotalCost != $totalCost)
```

With something a bit more tolerant of tiny differences such as:

```
if(abs($calculatedTotalCost - $totalCost) > 0.001)
```

The basic idea is that unlike integers, `floats` can have tiny variations in expected outcomes from arithmetic operations. If I had to guess I would say that `$calculatedTotalCost` has gone through some math ops and isn't *exactly* what you expect. It has to do with how computers store values.[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality

The safer approach is to measure whether the difference between the values falls within an acceptable range.

Comment: Well this worked but I'm still confused as to why it is necessary.

Comment: I don't know exactly because in the OP we don't have the full chain of events for `$totalCost` and `$calculatedCost`, but I've added to my answer for your benefit.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging this sort of problem, it's better to use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) than echo, since var_dump will give you information about the data type as well as just the value (as echo does).

eg. `echo $a` and `echo $b` might give you the same value, but `var_dump($a, $b)` is likely to show you the difference that is causing the comparison to fail.

However, there are inherent problems in comparing floating point numbers. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364189/comparing-floats-same-number-but-does-not-equal) and [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) in the PHP docs for discussion of the problem and potential solutions.

Comment: `float(46.45) float(46.45)` is the result of my `var_dump` of both of these variables...????

Comment: That's extremely strange. Are you doing the var_dump inside the if statement?

Comment: Yes it looks like this: `if($calculatedTotalCost != $totalCost){
   abort(500, 'Your Order Cost Is Incorrect!'.var_dump($calculatedTotalCost)." ".var_dump($totalCost));
   return;
     }`

Comment: Ah, it turns out the problem is with comparing floats at all. See my updated answer.