# Float Comparison in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to compare two floats in twig but I don't have the good result :

I have two 'equal' floats : float1 and float2

```
{% if float1 == float2 %}
   <span>Floats are equal</span>
{% else %}
   <span>Floats are different</span>
{% endif %}
{{ float1 == float2 }}
```

Display :

```
<span>Floats are different</span>
1
```

How can I compare two floats in Twig ?
I don't understand why the result of the comparison is true but the result of the if statement is false

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364189/comparing-floats-same-number-but-does-not-equal. [PHP's documentation will also help you](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

Comment: I know how floats works but I don't understand why the result of the comparison is different in the if statement and when I display it.
Also, is there a solution to compare floats in twig ?

Comment: A look at the generated cache file might reveal why they're different. Also: You compare floats in twig like you do everywhere else: You check their relative difference for some acceptable epsilon and consider them equal if the difference is below that.

Comment: I tried something like this : 
{% if (float1 - float2)|abs < 0.00001 %}

But this still goes in the else statement

Comment: Which version of Twig are you using? What are your values? I tried your example on [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/qyj0ld) and it behaves correctly.

Comment: Can you tell us some example values that you are comparing please?

Comment: The values are returned from a function but when I print them, I have 304 and 304
I am using version 1.24.1, I tried with this version in your twigfiddle and it gave me the right answer !
Also, when I try with the direct values, it works too ..
Is there something specific about returned values ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that I tried on Twigfiddle:

```
{% set float1 = 1.0123456789012 %}
{% set float2 = 1.0123456789011 %}

{% if float1 == float2 %}
   <span>Floats are equal</span>
{% else %}
   <span>Floats are different</span>
{% endif %}
```

The limit (at least on Twigfiddle) is 13 decimal places. So `1.0123456789012` works; but if you increase to `1.01234567890123`, the comparison won't work.

Here is the Twigfiddle for you to see it working: https://twigfiddle.com/r3hi48

Is your code any different than that? In other words in the above I use `set` to declare the two float variables. Have you also tried `{{ dump(float1) }}` to see what the value prints out as?

Comment: In fact, I noticed that my code works with numbers but I compare two floats returned by a function. Do you know if there is something specific about returned float values in Twig ?

Comment: Do you mean you are comparing using a function in your Controller? If so, can you edit your post and show `some` of the relevant code? Or maybe you mean something else? Have you tried the `{{ dump(float1) }}` function to see what the actual values are?

Comment: I passed to my template an intervention object, then I tried to compare the result of two functions (intervention.getPrice() == intervention.getPriceMin())
This gave me my comparison problem.
the dump showed the same value for the two float
I just had my template to work thanks to 'set', I set the return of my functions into variables and compare those variables. 
I think that I will delete this question and repost a question about why the returned values are not well interpreted
Thanks for your answer btw ! It helped me to find the set trick