# How to check if Math.cos(angle) = 0

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the correct domain for the `tan` function, I know that

```
tan x = sinx / cos x
```

and `tan` is undefined when `cos x = 0`. So

I am trying to check if `cos x`  is 0.

```
 if ( Math.Cos(x).Equals(0) )
 {
     // do stuff
 }
```

But this is never true because Math.Cos returns `6.123....E-17`
How o check for cos == 0 ?

Comment: since this uses double precision, you should add a reasonable error range.

Comment: Strange that no one ever tried to compare doubles before... http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+double+compare seems to be producing some results - possibly this is not first time...

Comment: It is only ever exactly 0 when the argument is exactly +/- pi/2.  It never is, floating point numbers don't have enough accuracy.

Comment: Why don't you check the value of x to be sure it's different from pi/2 + kpi ?

Comment: @FDL I thought about this but didn't know how  make the check.

Comment: Since your x is expressed as radians you have to convert to degrees with x * 180/Math.PI. For example if x==1.57 rad you'll have 90degrees and your cos(90) == 0, in fact 90 deg == Math.PI/2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to broaden your expectations a bit - in order for `Math.Cos(x)` to be genuinely equal to 0, you'd either need inaccuracy in `Cos` (which will happen, of course) or for `x` to have an irrational value.

Instead, you should work out some tolerance - some range of values for `Math.Cos` which is *very close* to 0. For example:

```
if (Math.Abs(Math.Cos(x)) < 1e-15)
```

That `1e-15` is picked pretty much arbitrarily - you should work out what you want it to be for your particular task. (This will still give pretty enormous `tan` values, of course...)

Comment: What about using `double.Epsilon`?

Comment: `double.Epsilon` is far too small.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328475/should-we-compare-floating-point-numbers-for-equality-against-a-relative-error

Comment: @user1620220: No, that's likely to be too small. In particular, *only* the values 0, `double.Epsilon` and `-double.Epsilon` are within `double.Epsilon` of 0... and I wouldn't like to say whether there is a `double` value `x` such that `Cos(x)` is one of those three values.

Comment: double.Epsilon is not an epsilon for fuzzy comparisson, but rather the smallest value that is not zero and can be represented in double-precision floating point number.

Comment: It's worth noting that usually these threshold values (ie :`1e-15`) will often depend on the nature of further calculations down the line.  In some cases (multiple derivatives, etc) you actually have to truncate much sooner than in others just to avoid the numbers exploding in subsequent calculations.  Your overall system will have a "generally calculable" domain and you typically have to figure out what that is in each situation.

Comment: For cos(x) approaching 0, tan(x) approaches 1/cos(x). So the tolerance can be selected such that tan(x) is maximum, hence it will be something around 1/double.MaxValue = 5.5626846E-309 >>> double.Epsilon = 4.940656E-324. Right?

Comment: @L16H7: Well, that assumes that the rest of the code can handle huge values too. In reality, the OP may well want to restrict the range to smaller values. It really depends on the rest of the OP's task - it's very context sensitive.

Comment: I know practically it depends on the task. I was trying to calculate the theoretical minimum value cos(x) can get for tan(x) to be below the MaxValue.

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is receiving an exception from [Math.Tan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.tan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Math.Tan` doesn't throw. The only thing it can do is return `Double.NaN` and (perhaps) `Double.PositiveInfinity`/`Double.NegativeInfinity`, so simply check for them:

```
double t = Math.Tan(something);

if (!double.IsInfinity(t) && !double.IsNaN(t))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to compare it not directly, but with some accuracy due to the fact how floating point values are represented in memory.

You can fix it by using some code like this one:

```
const double Epsilon = 0.0001;

if (Math.Cos(x) < Epsilon)
{
    // Code here
}
```

Also, there is not point in writing Math.Cos(x).Equals(something) because it makes code harder to read.

If you want more info on why your code doesn't work you can look it up here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html

This is a FAQ for C++, but same things apply in your case.