# How should I do an equality test for 80bit IEEE floating point?

Tags: floating-point, d, bit-manipulation

related to:

- [comparing ieee floats and doubles for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265/)
- [Should we compare floating point numbers for equality against a *relative* error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328475/)
- [Most effective way for float and double comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/#17467)

However with regard to [80 bit IEEE floats](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253665.pdf) (see section 8.2) on an x86

In particular I like the [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265/comparing-ieee-floats-and-doubles-for-equality#21277) using a count of representable values between the operands because it scale by default.

One use case would be for numeric approximations where two values approach each other and I need to check to see if they are close enough.

---

p.s. The implementation language will be D but I can translate. Also an implementation that can automatically handle whatever the underlying type is (for instance if only 64bit real was available) would be ideal.

[The current code in use:](http://www.dsource.org/projects/scrapple/browser/trunk/units/unit.d#L141)

Comment: "I'm wrapping FPs in a units type" (see my answer below,put here so it shows up on BCS' radar) sounds D-ish. Surely at some point you need to know what the data type is for comparison (i.e. unwrap it?).

Comment: [OT] @Pax: now that's a nice solution!!

Comment: [OT] http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/86757

Answer (score 2):

Since D has 80-bit reals built in (as far as I can tell), why would you not just use the standard approach of comparing with an epsilon value. This can be a fixed value if you know the rough range in advance, such as US currency:

```
if (abs (a - b) < 1e-6) // effectively equal
```

or an acceptable relative error, such as 1 part per million of the average:

```
if (abs (a - b) < ((a + b) / 2) / 1e6) // effectively equal
```

Keep in mind I don't know D, the code above is for demonstrative purposes only.

Comment: In my case, I'm wrapping FPs in a units type, so I literally have no special knowledge about the value range.

Comment: re your comment above: see the new link. The whole thing is a D redux of Boost::SI

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is

```
bool Near(real a, real b, int count = 5)
{
    // Returns the number of mantissa bits which are equal in x and y.
    int i = std.math.feqrel!(real)(a,b);
    return i + count >= real.mant_dig;
}
```

It gives the number of miss-matched bits in the inputs. I'm not sure how well this will work near powers of 2.